# boost zip_iterator and std::sort

Tags: c++, boost

I have two arrays `values` and `keys` both of the same length. 
I want to sort-by-key the `values` array using the `keys` array as keys.
I have been told the boost's zip iterator is just the right tool for **locking** two arrays together and doing stuff to them at the same time.

Here is my attempt at using the boost::zip_iterator to solve sorting problem which fails to compile with `gcc`. Can someone help me fix this code?

The problem lies in the line

`std::sort ( boost::make_zip_iterator( keys, values  ), boost::make_zip_iterator( keys+N  , values+N ));`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int N=10;
  int    keys[N];
  double values[N];
  int M=100;

  //Create the vectors.
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   {
     keys[i]   = rand()%M;
     values[i] = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
   }


  //Now we use the boost zip iterator to zip the two vectors and sort them "simulatneously"
  //I want to sort-by-key the keys and values arrays
   std::sort ( boost::make_zip_iterator( keys, values  ), 
               boost::make_zip_iterator( keys+N  , values+N    )
             );
    //The values array and the corresponding keys in ascending order. 
   for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
      std::cout << keys[i]   <<  "\t"  << values[i]    << std::endl;  
     }
  return 0;
}
```

NOTE:Error message on compilation

```
g++ -g -Wall boost_test.cpp 
boost_test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
boost_test.cpp:37:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_zip_iterator(int [(((unsigned int)(((int)N) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)], double [(((unsigned int)(((int)N) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)])’
boost_test.cpp:38:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_zip_iterator(int*, double*)’
```

Comment: As pointed out by carl-cook, there is more recent (duplicate) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840998/sorting-zipped-locked-containers-in-c-using-boost-or-the-stl) in which a working solution is given. Also note that Eric Niebler's range library provides view::zip which [just works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32720638/554283). Said library has been proposed for standardization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't sort a pair of zip_iterators.

Firstly, make_zip_iterator takes a tuple of iterators as input, so you could call:

```
boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple( ... ))
```

but that won't compile either, because `keys` and `keys+N` doesn't have the same type. We need to force `keys` to become a pointer:

```
std::sort(boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(+keys, +values)),
          boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(keys+N, values+N)));
```

this will compile, but the sorted result is still wrong, because a zip_iterator only models a [Readable iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html#zip-iterator-models), but `std::sort` also needs the input to be [Writable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html#writable-iterators-lib-writable-iterators) as [described here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html#changes-to-algorithm-requirements), so you can't sort using zip_iterator.

Comment: Thank you. This was useful But then how would I go about sorting-by-key the values array? I am sure it is a very common operation one encounters in C++

Comment: @curiousexplorer: The easiest way is to make it an array of `std::pair<int, double>` or `boost::tuple<int, double>`.

Comment: It does not compile: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aWPYbYvr9

Answer (score 5):

A very good discussion of this problem can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120422174751/http://www.stanford.edu/~dgleich/notebook/2006/03/sorting_two_arrays_simultaneou.html

Here's a possible duplicate of this question: [Sorting zipped (locked) containers in C++ using boost or the STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840998/sorting-zipped-locked-containers-in-c-using-boost-or-the-stl)

The approach in the link above uses std::sort, and no extra space. It doesn't employ boost::zip_iterator, just boost tuples and the boost iterator facade. Std::tuples should also work if you have an up to date compiler.

If you are happy to have one extra vector (of size_t elements), then the following approach will work in ~ o(n log n) time average case. It's fairly simple, but there will be better approaches out there if you search for them.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void sortByPerm(vector<T1>& list1, vector<T2>& list2) {
  const auto len = list1.size();
  if (!len || len != list2.size()) throw;

  // create permutation vector
  vector<size_t> perms;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) perms.push_back(i);
  sort(perms.begin(), perms.end(), [&](T1 a, T1 b){ return list1[a] < list1[b]; });

  // order input vectors by permutation
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    swap(list1[i], list1[perms[i]]);
    swap(list2[i], list2[perms[i]]);

    // adjust permutation vector if required
    if (i < perms[i]) {
      auto d = distance(perms.begin(), find(perms.begin() + i, perms.end(), i));
      swap(perms[i], perms[d]);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  vector<int> ints = {32, 12, 40, 8, 9, 15};
  vector<double> doubles = {55.1, 33.3, 66.1, 11.1, 22.1, 44.1};

  sortByPerm(ints, doubles);   

  copy(ints.begin(), ints.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); cout << endl;
  copy(doubles.begin(), doubles.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, " ")); cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing another of your comments in another answer.

I though I would enlighten you to the std::map. This is a key value container, that preserves key order. (it is basically a binary tree, usually red black tree, but that isn't important).

```
size_t elements=10;
std::map<int, double> map_;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    map_[rand()%M]=1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
}
//for every element in map, if you have C++11 this can be much cleaner
for (std::map<int,double>::const_iterator it=map_.begin(); 
         it!=map_.end(); ++it) 
{
    std::cout << it->first   <<  "\t"  << it->second  << std::endl;  
}
```

untested, but any error should be simple syntax errors

Comment: The key/value vectors have advantages compared to map. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223604/pair-of-vectors-instead-of-a-vectorpair

Answer (score -1):

`boost::make_zip_iterator` take a boost::tuple.

```
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> keys(10);      //lets not waste time with arrays
  std::vector<double> values(10);
  const int M=100;

  //Create the vectors.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
   {
     keys[i]   = rand()%M;
     values[i] = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;
   }


  //Now we use the boost zip iterator to zip the two vectors and sort them "simulatneously"
  //I want to sort-by-key the keys and values arrays
   std::sort ( boost::make_zip_iterator(
                    boost::make_tuple(keys.begin(), values.begin())), 
               boost::make_zip_iterator(
                     boost::make_tuple(keys.end(), values.end()))
             );
    //The values array and the corresponding keys in ascending order. 
   for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
      std::cout << keys[i]   <<  "\t"  << values[i]    << std::endl;  
     }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok this compiles. But it gives me a junk answer. Of the two columns which are being printed the first one is entirely 93 and the second entriely 0.197551

Comment: I am actually surprised it compiled at all at first, you need to make you own comparison function

Comment: It does not compile nowadays: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/va9ddo15d