# Sort one vector according to another

Tags: c++, sorting, root-framework

I'm basing my question off the answer to this one:

[How to obtain the index permutation after the sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554242/how-to-obtain-the-index-permutation-after-the-sorting)

I have two std::vectors:

```
std::vector<int> time={5, 16, 4, 7};   
std::vector<int> amplitude={10,17,8,16};
```

I want to order the vectors for increasing time, so eventually they will be:

```
TimeOrdered={4,5,7,16};
AmplitudeOrdered={8,10,16,17};
```

Once finished, I want to add both ordered vectors to a CERN ROOT TTree. I looked online for solutions and found the example above, where the top answer is to use the following code:

```
vector<int> data = {5, 16, 4, 7};   
vector<int> index(data.size(), 0);
for (int i = 0 ; i != index.size() ; i++) {
    index[i] = i;
}
sort(index.begin(), index.end(),[&](const int& a, const int& b) {
                return (data[a] < data[b]);
              }
  );
for (int ii = 0 ; ii != index.size() ; ii++) {
  cout << index[ii] << endl;
}
```

Which I like because it's simple, it doesn't require too many lines and it leaves me with two simple vectors, which I can then use easily for my TTree.

I tried, therefore, to generalise it:

```
  void TwoVectorSort(){

      std::vector<int> data={5, 16, 4, 7};   
      std::vector<int> data2={10,17,8,16};
      sort(data2.begin(), data2.end(),[&](const int& a, const int& b) {
                        return (data[a] < data[b]);
                      }
        );

      for (int ii = 0 ; ii != data2.size() ; ii++) {
        std::cout <<data[ii]<<"\t"<< data2[ii]<<"\t"<< std::endl;//<<index[ii] 
      }
}
```

But not only does it not work, it gives me something different each time. I'm running it as a macro with ROOT 6.18/04, using .x TwoVectorSort.cpp+.

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work and what the simplest solution is? I'm by no means a c++ expert so I hope the answers won't be too technical!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Sort based on other int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486870/c-sort-based-on-other-int-array)

Comment: That's another useful answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can re-use the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554242/how-to-obtain-the-index-permutation-after-the-sorting) from the link you shared to solve your problem. But you need to keep building the `index` vector (and I believe there's no need to modify the `time` or `amplitude` vectors).

The `index` vector is used to store the [index/position](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/) of the `time` vector values sorted from smallest to largest, so for `time={5, 16, 4, 7}`:

> `index[0]` will contain the index of the smallest value from `time` (which is `4`, at position 2), hence `index[0]=2`
>
> `index[1]` will contain the index of the 2nd smallest value from `time` (which is `5`, at position 0), hence `index[1]=0`
>
> etc.

And since `amplitude`'s order is based on `time` you can use `index[pos]` to access both vectors when building your tree:

> `time[index[pos]]` and `amplitude[index[pos]]`

Code with the corrections:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int  main(){

    std::vector<int> time={5, 16, 4, 7};
    std::vector<int> amplitude={10,17,8,16};
    std::vector<int> index(time.size(), 0);

    for (int i = 0 ; i != index.size() ; i++) {
        index[i] = i;
    }

    sort(index.begin(), index.end(),
         [&](const int& a, const int& b) {
            return (time[a] < time[b]);
          }
    );

    std::cout << "Time \t Ampl \t idx" << std::endl;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii != index.size() ; ++ii) {
        std::cout << time[index[ii]] << " \t " << amplitude[index[ii]] << " \t " << index[ii] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Time     Ampl    idx
4        8       2
5        10      0
7        16      3
16       17      1
```

---

> But not only does it not work, it gives me **something different each time**

That happened because the parameters that the [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) was receiving were from `data2={10,17,8,16}` and those values were being used as index to access the `data` vector at `return (data[a] < data[b])`. It caused some random sorting because it was accessing out of the vector's range and reading garbage from memory (hence the random behavior).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'd never seen the syntax for the lambda before, and I've looked at the link you provided but I found it very technical. Would you mind explaining it to me in a really simple way? What exactly does it do and how does it do it?
Thanks a lot again!

Comment: (yw!) A simple way (and imprecise, though) would be: lambda expressions are a way to define functions within functions. [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) receives 3 parameters: first 2 are elements from the vector and the 3rd one is a function (aka functor) used to compare the previous 2 elements. With a lambda you can inline the comparison function and avoid creating a function outside. You will find much better explanations about lambdas in [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11).

Comment: Ok, that link is really useful thanks! So to try and really understand:
The lambda takes all variables currently in scope into its capture list [&], initiates two constant integer variables as arguments (const int& a, const int& b) and returns... what? Isn't time[a] < time[b] a bool? And how does the lambda know what values of a and b to use?
Really trying to learn something new! Thanks again :)

Comment: The parameters have to do with std::sort ( [sort explained for beginners](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz) ). It would be the same if you were using a function ([same code but using a function](https://ideone.com/qXW8L0)) because sort will be calling the lambda/function with two parameters each time from the vector. Both the lambda and the custom function need to return a bool because that's what std::sort uses to compare each pair of elements so it can get the whole structure sorted.

Comment: Please disregard the output of the above code snippet since it is just to illustrate the difference between a sort using lambda and using a function. You can [change the comparison function to be greater than and it will sort the opposite way](https://ideone.com/ZIbTWD). I hope it helps! Do not hesitate to open separate questions if you have doubts not related to the initial one.