# Passing vector in template argument

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I want to define a compare function so that it can be passed to std::sort. The comparision needs to be done based on the ordering of the vector x as demonstrated in 'compare_by_x' function below.

```
template <std::vector<double> x>
bool compare_by_x(int i, int j){
  return x[i] <= x[j];
}
```

I want to pass the compare_by_x function as follows. This is not working.

```
std::sort(some_index_vector.begin(), some_index_vector.end(), compare_by_x<x>);
```

Comment: What is the x in `compare_by_x<x>`?

Comment: Are you getting an error at compile time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [boost zip\_iterator and std::sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343846/boost-zip-iterator-and-stdsort)

Comment: Use a zip iterator to sort *pairs*.

Comment: Firstly, you can't pass `std::vector` as nontype template parameter.

Comment: @mattn , x is std::vector<double>

Comment: Probably, it will become more easy with using lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass object references to template or to function.
But you can pass them to structs.

Here is working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct compare_by_x
{
    std::vector<double>& x;
    compare_by_x(std::vector<double>& _x) : x(_x) {}

    bool operator () (int i, int j)
    {
        return x[i] <= x[j];
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<double> some_index_vector;
    some_index_vector.push_back(0);
    some_index_vector.push_back(1);
    some_index_vector.push_back(2);
    std::vector<double> x;
    x.push_back(3);
    x.push_back(1);
    x.push_back(2);

    std::sort(some_index_vector.begin(), some_index_vector.end(), compare_by_x(x));

    for (std::vector<double>::const_iterator it = some_index_vector.begin(); it != some_index_vector.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot do that – templates are for types and a few compile-time constants only.

You need to take a look at the [documentation of `std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), which explains what kind of comparison function is expected as the third argument. Yours wouldn’t work even if the template *did* miraculously compile.

Luckily for you, the solution to your problem [has already been posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236199/1968).