# sorting table in place using stl sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

I have a HUGE table (about 50Gb) in (i,j,k) format (from a sparse matrix) stored as

```
uint32_t * idx1, * idx2;
float * vals;
uint32_t tablesize;
```

and I'd like to sort it in place with a given comparison function that's a function of idx1 and idx2. Can this be done using std::sort?

Specifically, each nonzero entry (i,j) with value v in the sparse matrix is stored by placing i in idx1, j in idx2, and v in the corresponding entry in vals. I'd like to then sort these entries according to (i1, j1, v1) <= (i2, j2, v2) if

```
(i1 < i2) || (i1==i2 && j1 <= j2)
```

The examples I've been able to scrounge up of using std::sort on nonstandard datatypes assume that each item being compared is a single instance of a class; here each item is represented by three values in different arrays.

Comment: In a nutshell, look at the 3 argument version of `std::sort`, and then look up `functor` or `function object`.

Comment: So you need to help up -- if I give you two (i,j,k) values values tell us how you would determine if the first value comes before the second value.  Also what form is this "table"?  You need to tell us a little bit more detail as to how this data is structured.

Comment: So you want all three arrays sorted? The easiest would be to combine them all into a `struct` and just have a single array of that type.

Comment: I don't see how to use the three argument version of sort. What would the RandomAccessIterator be here? That's what I meant about nonstandard datatypes: examples are available for how to deal with this kind of problem if your values are stored as a single class object as Jonathan recommended (this is infeasible for me, since constructing such a struct as a second copy of my data I'd run out of memory), but nothing about if your data is distributed across several arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to keep using your existing data structure, which is essentially a `std::tuple` of three `std::vector`s, using `boost::zip_iterator` would *seem* to be the way to go. A `zip_iterator` treats three iterators (two to indices and one to a value) as a single tuple, and you can use a custom comparison function object to sort your data in-place. Alas, `boost::zip_iterator` can't be used with `std::sort`, as explained in [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343991/819272), because it can't be written into.

This means that you would have to write your own zip_iterator class that can be used with `std::sort`. Note that it is not a trivial exercise, see [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840998/sorting-zipped-locked-containers-in-c-using-boost-or-the-stl) and/or this [**paper**](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/articles/pair_iterators.pdf).

It is a lot easier to sort a `std::vector` of a `std::tuple`. My attempt below uses a `std::tuple` of two indices and a value, and stores those entries into a `std::vector`. For the sorting, I use a C++14 generic lambda that forwards the two indices into a smaller tuple and compares those lexicographically (i.e. first on row-index, then on column-index) using the library `operator<` of `std::tuple`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using index = uint32_t;
using value = float;
using sparse_entry = std::tuple<index, index, value>;
using sparse_matrix = std::vector<sparse_entry>;

int main()
{
    // sparse 3x3 matrix
    auto m = sparse_matrix { 
        std::make_tuple( 1, 1, -2.2), 
        std::make_tuple( 1, 0, 42  ), 
        std::make_tuple( 0, 2,  3.4), 
        std::make_tuple( 0, 1,  1.7) 
    };    

    // sort by row-index, then column-index
    std::sort(begin(m), end(m), [](auto const& L, auto const& R) {
        return 
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<0>(L), std::get<1>(L)) <
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<0>(R), std::get<1>(R))
        ;
    });

    for (auto const& elem : m)
        std::cout << "{ " << std::get<0>(elem) << ", " << std::get<1>(elem) << ", " << std::get<2>(elem) << "}, \n";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc662d91c10921c2).

If your application can use this transformed data layout (and there maybe cache-performance reasons why it can't), then the above code will do the sorting as you want it.

**NOTE**: as @Casey mentions, you can also use `std::tie` instead of `std::forward_as_tuple`, but that can bite you when you change `sparse_entry` into a full-fledged user-defined class with getters returning by-value.

Comment: `std::tie` is a bit quicker to type than `std::forward_as_tuple`, and has the same effect in this instance.

Comment: @Casey `std::tie` only takes lvalues, whereas `std::forward_as_tuple` also works for getters returning by-value. Also, it used to be the case that `std::tie` was not `constexpr`, so I have fallen into the habit of not using `std::tie`.

Comment: There are no overloads of `std::get` that return by value, and it's nearly impossible to extend since (a) it's forbidden to overload functions in `std`, and (b) it's not possible to partially specialize functions. It would also be fairly perverse for such an extension to return by value when passed an lvalue. In any case, I did edit my comment to add "in this instance" ;)

Comment: @Casey updated my answer, tnx! btw, with getters you'd write something like `std::tie(L.row(), L.column())` instead of `std::get` of course

Comment: Ah, I see. I mistook "getters" in your comment to mean flavors of `std::get`. That makes more sense now.

Comment: I thought this answer was brilliant, but then I looked into it and found that `zip_iterator` cannot be written into. Such a shame! I wanted it to be true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343846/boost-zip-iterator-and-stdsort

Comment: @StilesCrisis Thanks for pointing out that `boost::zip_iterator` can't be written into. Fortunately, the solution in the cited paper by Anthony Williams can. Updated the answer, thanks again.

Comment: I ended up implementing this; it works way faster than the custom mergesort I had written... but is std::sort guarantee to work in-place?

Comment: @AlexGittens yes, `std::sort` is in-place, unlike `std::stable_sort`

Answer (score 3):

It is unfortunately quite difficult to convince `std::sort`, or any of the standard library, to work with striped data. It is designed to assume that data can be copied via a single `=`, moved via one `move` or swapped via one `swap`.

Your best bet is to use `boost::iterator_facade` to write a custom iterator class which wraps the data, and hides the striped data format from `std::sort`. I've wanted to do something similar in the past but my workspace does not allow us to use `boost`. **EDIT:** when your facade is dereferenced, it will probably need to create some sort of proxy object that can be assigned/moved/swapped and will do the right thing to each of the stripe arrays. It's not trivial.

The next best bet is to make an array of `int`s from zero to N, each one representing an index into your striped data array. Write a custom functor to `std::sort` which sorts this array to match your criteria. It's obviously far from ideal when you have such a large data set.

Comment: I think this answer is closest to what you want, but you may want to consider rolling your own sort optimized for truly huge arrays; 50 GB of data, even if its in RAM is better treated with external sorting algorithms to exploit locality of access  better; it's also a fair bet that you'll benefit from a parallel sort as well.

Comment: Good point. I was answering "can you use `std::sort` here" and not "*should* you". All the gymnastics I've listed above are likely going to be more effort than just copy-pasting a basic `qsort` implementation and tweaking it to suit your needs, and the hand-tweaked implementation is likely to be faster as well.

Comment: An iterator that returns a proxy when dereferenced is not a RandomAccessIterator, since ForwardIterators (and hence anything more refined) are required to return `value_type&` or `const value_type&` when dereferenced. (per [forward.iterators]/1.3)