# How to sort one array and get corresponding second array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays in same size. And want to sort one of the array normally and then sort the next array elements accordingly.
Let's say we have two arrays

```
e[] = {4,2,3,7,6,8}
s[] = {2,0,4,3,7,9}
```

First I want to sort array `e` normally, Then change the element positions of `s` array according to the changed element positions of `e`.

This should be the final result

```
e[] = {2,3,4,6,7,8}
s[] = {0,4,2,7,3,9}
```

How should I do this? Should I use a class object with these two as private members and then proceed? If so, how to do that?

Comment: **When stymied, try something simpler.** If you had only one array, how would you sort it?

Comment: seems like you have wrong Data Structure. you should try using two dimensional array instead.

Comment: You may want to check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343846/boost-zip-iterator-and-stdsort,  and the links in the answers of that question too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a single array (or [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) of [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) objects, where `first` is from the first array and `second` from the second. Then just use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a custom comparator function that uses only `second` from the pair for comparison. Iterate over the sorted array (or vector) and split up into the original arrays.

Note: If the values in each array are tightly coupled then consider putting them in a structure or class instead of using two (or more) distinct arrays.

Answer (score 1):

- What I think is use `std::map`
- Assign array `e` element as the key
- And corresponding array `s` element as the value.
- Then sort the may by key
- Go trough the map and get the values one by one

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is already sorted by key, no need for a separate sorting step.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in a class, you can create an array of indices and sort the indices according to the values in e[]. If not doing this within a class, and for a more general approach, create an array of pointers to e[], then sort the pointers according to e[]. Then reorder e[] and s[] according to the pointers, converting the the sorted pointers to an index by using array_of_pointers[i] - &e[0] (or just array_of_pointers[i]-e). You could write your own sort, or use qsort, std::sort, or std::stable sort to sort the array of pointers, with a compare function that compares using dereferenced pointers (compares the values pointed to). Example C code using qsort and reorder in place logic with O(n) time complexity:

```
int compare(const void *pp0, const void *pp1)
{
    int i0 = **(int **)pp0;
    int i1 = **(int **)pp1;
    if(i0 > i1)return -1;
    if(i0 < i1)return  1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
int e[...];
int s[...];
int *pe[...];
size_t i, j, k;
int te, ts;
    /* ... */
    /* create array of pointers to e[] */
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]); i++)
        pe[i] = &e[i];
    /* sort array of pointers */
    qsort(pe, sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]), sizeof(pe[0]), compare);
    /* reorder e[] and s[] according to the array of pointers */
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]); i++){
        if(i != pe[i]-e){
            te = e[i];
            ts = s[i];
            k = i;
            while(i != (j = pe[k]-e)){
                e[k] = e[j];
                s[k] = s[j];
                pe[k] = &e[k];
                k = j;
            }
            e[k] = te;
            s[k] = ts;
            pe[k] = &e[k];
        }
    }
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use other Data structures and stick with the two different integer arrays..

Following code snippet will help you

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int e[] = {4,2,3,7,6,8} ;
    int s[] = {2,0,4,3,7,9} ;
    int temp ;

    int Array_Size = 6 ; // don't use hard coded value here, rather calculate from array size

    for(int i = 0 ; i < Array_Size ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1 ; j < Array_Size ; j++)
        {
            if(e[i] > e[j])
            {
                // Swap elements in first array
                temp = e[j] ;
                e[j] = e[i] ;
                e[i] = temp ;

                // As you want both arrays in sync 
                // Swap elements in second array here itself
                temp = s[j] ;
                s[j] = s[i] ;
                s[i] = temp ;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple when we use structure.Your basic task is to sort two arrays. I want to suggest one method regarding it. Use a structure having two variables x and y which are used here for two arrays. Make two array of objects of this structure.

```
  struct Point
        {
         int x,y;
        };
  struct Point arr[n];
```

After providing entries to the array of structure objects, make use of STL function

```
sort(arr,arr+n,myfun);
```

where myfun is function to sort according to ur need and it is defined as

```
bool myfun(struct Point a,struct Point b)
{
  if(a.x<b.x)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

And here is the complete program in c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct Point{
             int x,y;
            };
bool myfun(struct Point a,struct Point b)
{
  if(a.x<b.x)
      return true;
  else
      return false;
}
int main()
{
    int n;  //n is the number of elements of array
    cin>>n;
    struct Point arr[n];
    //Enter first array
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i].x;
    //Enter second array
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i].y;
    //sorting with the help of myfun
    sort(arr,arr+n,myfun);
    //now print the arrays
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<arr[i].x<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<arr[i].y<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void bubbleSort(int e[], int s[], int n) {
      bool swapped = true;
      int j = 0;
      int tmp;
      while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            j++;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++) {
                  if (e[i] > e[i + 1]) {
                        tmp = e[i];
                        e[i] = e[i + 1];
                        e[i + 1] = tmp;
                        tmp = s[i];
                        s[i] = s[i + 1];
                        s[i + 1] = tmp;

                        swapped = true;
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Bad suggestion to implement sort yourself (and not the best one to start with), and this is *not* C++ way of dealing with sequences. To make it into ok answer please provide good explanation of the approach and why it is better than `std::` algorithms.

Comment: you think i don't know how to solve this problem using std::sort?? you are assuming that every problem u get conforms to C++ way. What if it was an existing design?? my solution just works for the problem stated by OP

Comment: Nandu - the only "assumption" I've made (and I hope it is reasonable one) that post does not include explanation. Even simple "copy-paste ready solution for assignment 345" line of text would be enough (to clarify that approach should only be taken for particular assignment in particular school). Otherwise since you suggested non-standard approach you should provide explanation (no one on SO really cares what poster knows -  we care to see complete information in questions/answers).

Comment: if one can read C++ code, they don't need an explanation...since you have asked for one, i'll provide.. while sorting array e[], my solution simply swaps corresponding indices of s[]. What i have done is to provide a reasonable answer based on OP's question. HTH