# Sorting two arrays using C++23 zip view

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

There is a rather typical task of sorting two arrays simultaneously, assuming that same indexed elements of the arrays form virtual pairs, which are sorted. Such questions appear at least 10 years ago: [boost zip_iterator and std::sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343846/boost-zip-iterator-and-stdsort)

Now this task can be solved using [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library:

```
#include <array>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main() {
   auto x = std::array{ 3,   2,   4,   1 };
   auto y = std::array{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
   ranges::sort( ranges::views::zip( x, y ) );
   // here x = {1,2,3,4}, y={'D','B','A','C'}
}
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WGo4vGsx5

In C++23 [std::ranges::zip_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view) appears, and my expectation was that the same program can be written using the standard library only:

```
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   auto x = std::array{ 3,   2,   4,   1 };
   auto y = std::array{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
   std::ranges::sort( std::views::zip( x, y ) );
}
```

Unfortunately, it results in long compilation errors. E.g. in GCC:

```
...
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221127/include/c++/13.0.0/bits/ranges_algo.h:54:31: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(std::ranges::less&, std::pair<int, char>&, std::pair<int&, char&>)'
   54 |           return std::__invoke(__comp,
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
   55 |                                std::__invoke(__proj, std::forward<_TL>(__lhs)),
      |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   56 |                                std::__invoke(__proj, std::forward<_TR>(__rhs)));
      |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/47xrzM6ch

Is it just because the implementations are not mature enough yet, or `zip` view in `C++23` will not help to sort two array?

Comment: With [p2165r4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf) the `zip_view` shouldn't use a `std::pair` anymore (instead always a `std::tuple`). This seems to not be implemented yet. With `std::pair` I am not sure whether this was meant to work. A `std::pair` to references (`iter_reference_t<I>`) is not comparable with a `std::pair` to values (`iter_value_t<I>`) without conversion, but `std::ranges::sort` requires that `iter_reference_t<I>` and `iter_value_t<I>&` are comparable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least the trunk version of libc++ (llvm) supports this:

```cpp
std::ranges::sort(std::views::zip(x, y), [](auto&& a, auto&& b) {
    return std::tie(std::get<0>(a), std::get<1>(a)) < 
           std::tie(std::get<0>(b), std::get<1>(b));
});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aP9Pqzjf4)

If you use three ranges instead of two, it works without having to supply a user-defined comparator function:

```cpp
auto x = std::array{ 3,   2,   4,   1 };
auto y = std::array{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
auto z = std::array{"Z", "Y", "X", "W"};

std::ranges::sort(std::views::zip(x, y, z));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hP88e1n6P)

I assume the version that zips two ranges will not need a user-defined comparator function when fully implemented.

Comment: Sidenote, you can create a tuple from a pair directly, without `tie`: `std::tuple{some_pair}`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes, that's a nice simplification.

Answer (score 2):

Following with ***@Ted Lyngmo***'s demo, I have created my own:

```cpp
std::ranges::sort( zipped_xy, []<typename T, typename U>(T a, U b) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\t' << std::get<0>(a) << ':' << std::get<0>(b) << '\n';
    return std::tuple{a} < std::tuple{b};
});
```

[link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TacKaMY9x)

Running this, should give you some output like:

```
<lambda(T, U)> [with T = std::pair<int&, char&>; U = std::pair<int&, char&>]    2:3
<lambda(T, U)> [with T = std::pair<int&, char&>; U = std::pair<int&, char&>]    4:2
<lambda(T, U)> [with T = std::pair<int, char>; U = std::pair<int&, char&>]      4:3
<lambda(T, U)> [with T = std::pair<int&, char&>; U = std::pair<int&, char&>]    7:2
 ⋮
```

The problem here is that after the second iteration returning false, it will try to pass a `pair<int&, char&>` as a `pair<int, char>`, which cannot be compared with a `pair<int&, char&>`, which is why we needed to provide a custom comparator.

---

Why does it create copies of the underlying objects? I don't know*. The good news is that with [P2165R4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf), the value type for a `zip_view` will always be `tuple<Ts&...>`. Since `tuple<Ts...>` and `tuple<Ts&...>` can be compared directly, the `sort` will also be done automatically.

<sup>Note*: more discussion about this can be found in the comment.</sup>

Comment: "_Why does it create copies of the underlying objects? I don't know._": The typical sort implementation will do insertion sort for small ranges. For this it makes sense to move the element that is to be inserted into a local variable. And the `std::sortable` concept requires that the value is comparable with the reference, so that this should be allowed.

Comment: @user17732522 I understand that it might create copies of the underlying objects of the `zip_view`(the `pair`). What I meant is I don't know why it would also copy the underlying object of the underlying object of `zip_view`(the `int` and `char`).

Comment: Because copying the `iter_reference_t` (the pair with the references) would not move any of the actual values that are being sorted. The insertion sort will shift the other elements in the range, overwriting the current value. So it needs to be stored somewhere.

Comment: @user17732522 Hmm, didn't realize `sort(zip_view)` will actually sort the underlying range, thought it was only done on the view.

Comment: The point of a "_view_" is that it doesn't own any elements but just refers to the elements of the original range(s).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to passing in a custom comparator (as in other answers), you can pass in a custom projection function to project `pair`s into `tuple`s:

```
ranges::sort(views::zip(x, y), {}, [](auto p) { return std::tuple(p); });
```

which will cast `pair<int&, char&>` into `tuple<int&, char&>`, making `ranges::less` work properly.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5njjbW97s)

However, since C++23 changed the `value_type` of `zip_view`' iterator to always `tuple` (before that, `zip_view` will especially use `pair` as `value_type` when the number of range is `2`), your code is well-formed in C++23.

The only thing you have to do is wait for the compiler to implement [P2165](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Even shorter workaround would be to repeat one of the input arrays e.g. : `std::ranges::sort( std::views::zip( x, y, y ) );`. It works in GCC, but not in Clang: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rWd86E5Kb Is it expected to work everywhere?

Comment: @Fedor I don't think this is valid code, you zipped the same sequence and sorted, I suspect this is undefined behavior. This should be due to different algorithm implementations.