# Python array management C++ equivalent

Tags: c++, python, opencv, numpy, port

I know SO is not rent-a-coder, but I have a really simple python example that I need help translating to C++

```
grey_image_as_array = numpy.asarray( cv.GetMat( grey_image ) )

non_black_coords_array = numpy.where( grey_image_as_array > 3 )

# Convert from numpy.where()'s two separate lists to one list of (x, y) tuples:
non_black_coords_array = zip( non_black_coords_array[1], non_black_coords_array[0] )
```

First one is rather simple I guess - a linear indexable array is created with what bytes are retruned from `cv.GetMat`, right?

What would be an equivalent of pyton's `where` and especially this `zip` functions?

Comment: For zip, have a look at this question (you should be able to use boost::zip_iterator): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11

Comment: You don't need `zip()` in a C++ equivalent, since you'd write the code in a way that `non_black_coords_array` has the desired structure right away.  It is needed in Python because you cannot control the output format of `numpy.where()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about OpenCV, so I can't tell you what `cv.GetMat()` does.  Apparently, it returns something that can be used as or converted to a two-dimensional array.  The C or C++ interface to OpenCV that you are using will probably have a similarly names function.

The following lines create an array of index pairs of the entries in `grey_image_as_array` that are bigger than `3`.  Each entry in `non_black_coords_array` are zero based x-y-coordinates into `grey_image_as_array`.  Given such a coordinates pair `x`, `y`, you can access the corresponsing entry in the two-dimensional C++ array `grey_image_as_array` with `grey_image_as_array[y][x]`.

The Python code has to avoid explicit loops over the image to achieve good performance, so it needs to make to with the vectorised functions NumPy offers.  The expression `grey_image_as_array > 3` is a vectorised comparison and results in a Boolean array of the same shape as `grey_image_as_array`.  Next, `numpy.where()` extracts the indices of the `True` entries in this Boolean array, but the result is not in the format described above, so we need `zip()` to restructure it.

In C++, there's no need to avoid explicit loops, and an equivalent of `numpy.where()` would be rather pointless -- you just write the loops  and store the result in the format of your choice.

Comment: Sven, in my case the final destination would be C#, since I am not a C++ developer, so I don't know even how to write what you are explaining in C++. I know you have extended your answer, but could you also please write a c++ loop you are mentioning to do this >3 filtering?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov: That will look very similar to C#, the loops itself probably identical.  The difficult part is what data type to use for the target array, and that depends on what is done with the result further on.  Without more context, I can't give further advice.