# Use std::count to count equal values in a pair of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, counter

Given a pair of equal length arrays . .

```
void someFunc (const float **inputChannelData)
{
    const float* L = inputChannelData[0];
    const float* R = inputChannelData[1];
    ...
```

I can see that it is pretty easy to count the number of occurrences of a constant value using `std::count`  . .

```
std::count(L, L+someIntegerOffset, 0.0f)
```

... but is there a standard algorithm (or idiom) that counts the element-wise (same index in each array) number of identical values in two arrays?

A Matlab equivalent would look like `sum(L==R)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::count` has a predicate form `std::count_if`, and [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) suggest it gets the argument by lvalue.

So I believe I could hack together a lambda that captures the two arrays, from &arg gets the distance/index, then checks both values.  I doubt I would use it that way though instead of old-fashioned for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` for this, look here [Sequence-zip function for c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11)

And then `count_if` with predicate, that tuple has only identical elements.

Also, you can simply create array of pairs and do the same.

Something like this for count with pairs.

```
void someFunc(const float** inputChannelData, size_t offset)
{
   const float* R = inputChannelData[0];
   const float* L = inputChannelData[1];
   std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pairs;
   std::transform(L, L + offset, R, std::back_inserter(pairs),
   [](float l, float r)
   {
      return std::make_pair(l, r);
   });
   size_t equal_pairs = std::count_if(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(),
   [](const std::pair<float, float>& p)
   {
      return p.first == p.second;
   });
}
```