# comma operator with c++11 for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, foreach, comma-operator

I wanted at first to try if it was allowed to do something like :

```
vector<int> a{1, 2};
vector<int> b{3, 4};

for(auto ai : a, auto bi : b)
{

}
```

This didn't work but I was expecting it because of the size constraint.

However, I was surprised that this didn't work either :

```
vector<int> b{3, 4};

for(int x = 1, auto bi : b)
{

}
```

Isn't the comma operator meant to resolve every side effect of its left-side before going on the right side ?

Comment: Use `zip` method of boolinq library :) https://github.com/k06a/boolinq

Comment: The comma operator has nothing to do with this. This is a _declaration_.

Comment: @k06a I do not see any zip method in your repository.

Comment: @Arpegius you are right. It is not yet implemented in 2.0. My mistake...

Comment: Well, I found solution for this [sequence-zip-function-for-c11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case you have a declaration. Declarations can contain declarations of multiple variables, *separated by a comma*.

What you're writing in the second case is equivalent to the following declaration

```
int x = 1, auto bi;

for (...) ...
```

And the reason that the first didn't work is not because of any size constraint, but because of the syntax of a [range `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) simply doesn't allow you to do something like that.

Comment: Okay! But `for(auto ai = a.begin(), bi : b)` should work then ? (I know, it is weird and dangerous!)

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier No, the syntax doesn't allow that either. Please follow the link and read about how a range-based for loop might be implemented and you will understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator is an *operator.* Which means it can only be used in expressions. `int x = 1, auto bi : b` is definitely not an expression. So you cannot really use it there.

It looks a bit like a malformed declaration. Malformed because you're trying to change the type being declared.

Note that the grammar of the language actually uses a special nonterminal *for-range-declaration* for the piece on the left-hand side of `:`. Which eventually resolves to a single declaration. So it's illegal to declare more than one variable in the range-based for loop.

Comment: Okay, I wanted to know if there was some special construct in the grammar for this case precisely!