# How to implement an iterator for coupled arrays?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I have my own class that describes some mathematical vector of complex numbers. Wherein a real and complex parts of it are stored separately.

```
class Vector{
private:
  unsigned int dim; //dimensionality of vector
  double* real;
  double* imag;
};
```

I knowingly don't use a single array of `std::complex<double>` because inside the `Vector` there are some high performance routines which work with a real and complex parts of vector separately.

Now I want to implement an iterator that should return pointer to an appropriate elements of my vector and should has type `std::complex<double>`.

In other words the question is "how to organize an access to two coupled arrays through iterator of different type?"

Of course I don't want to store an additional array of `std::complex` as well as to do a conversion from my arrays to required one during calling of the iterator.

Please help me to implement just some basic operations such as `begin()` and `end()`.

Comment: Why not simply using `std::vector<pair<double,double>>` instead of rolling your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sequence-zip function for c++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11)

Comment: Do you really care about building it yourself, or is knowing about the existing (in Boost) zip_iterator good enough?