# What is the alternative to nested for loops in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

In Python, code like this:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
  for j in range(1, 10):
    # Do something here
```

Can be replaced by code like this:

```
from itertools import product
  for i, j in product(range(1, 10), repeat=2):
    # Do something here
```

Is there some equivalent in C++?

Comment: can try do while() or while() for nested loops

Comment: Well, `itertools.product` is not really an alternative to nested for loops, it's an alternative to that particular pattern of nested for loops. Anyhow, it can be done by defining some special iterators, but AFAIK there's nothing ready made for that in the standard library.

Comment: There is no direct language feature to do this specifically, but it's possible to write C++ scaffolding that achieves it.  The problem is that it will be less efficient than nested loops, harder for your compiler to optimize, and very irritating for other C++ programmers to read.

Comment: @paddy: well, exactly as the Python equivalent, I guess. =)

Comment: Eric Lippert's range-v3 or the corresponding TS sounds like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loops in C are exceedingly simple and can be adapted to a variety of needs, the syntax `for (init; condition; increment)` accepts function calls in all of the 3 fields, allowing you to emulate any iteration pattern just by placing code in there calling the functions that generate the information you need on each loop.

Because of that possibility, it is unusual to use "ranges" like in Python. In C it makes more sense to calculate each index as you loop.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least 2 ways

A) [Traditional multi-variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) for loop (for the lack of better name)

```
for(int i =0, int j=0 ; i < 10 && j < 10;i++, j++) {
}
```

B) Using [boost::zip_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) as mentioned in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11)

Comment: Your example A is not the same - it'll execute 10 times, not 100 - and `I == j` in each iteration.