# C++ Create a std::vector<float> const& object

Tags: c++, vector, constants

I have one vector::

```
static const std::vector<float> vector1
```

and one reference of a vector:

```
std::vector<float> const& vector2
```

I need to multiply the values of these vectors with each other and store them in  a new vector.

For example:

```
result[0]=vector1[0]*vector2[0]
result[1]=vector1[1]*vector2[1]
```

Then I need to give this vector to a method which only accepts:

```
std::vector<float> const& result
```

How do I do this in C++?

Comment: that's not an address, that's a reference. You're mixing up C and C++ constructs.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11#8513803 but may carry too much dependencies

Comment: changed adress to reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::vector<float> result;
std::transform(
    vector1.begin(), vector1.end(),
    vector2.begin(),
    std::back_inserter(result), std::multiplies<float>());

CallMethodThatTakesReferenceToVector(result);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PHYOI18504)

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. I get a compiler error, that transform can not find an overloading function. StoryTellers edit works