# Custom iterator returning std::pair of custom container elements (no boost)

Tags: c++

I have a class simplified as much as possible and for demonstration purposes. It looks as simple as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Simple
{
private:
    std::vector<std::size_t> indices;
    std::vector<int> values;
public:
    void insert(std::size_t index, int value)
    {
        indices.push_back(index);    
        values.push_back(value);
    }
    int at(std::size_t index)
    {
        return values[indices[index]];    
    }
};

int main()
{
    Simple s;
    s.insert(10, 100);
    std::cout << s.at(10) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I wat to achieve is to iterate over elements of this container and get std::pair at each iteration, whose `first` element would be a value from `indices` member and whose `second` element would be a value from `values` member. Something like:

```
Simple s;
s.insert(10, 100);
for (std::pair<std::size_t, int> node : s)
{
    std::cout << node.first << " " << node.second << std::endl; // expect to print 10 100
}
```

I'm really new to iterators. I know how to iterate through standard containers and get their values. I even know how to iterate through my `Simple` container and get value from `values` member at each iteration. I could do it like so:

```
//new member functions in Simple class
auto begin()
{
    std::begin(values);
}

auto end()
{
    std::end(values);
}
```

But I do not know how to create some new data type at each iteration and return it to the client code.

Comment: Your example code in `main` will produce undefined behavior. It looks like you're trying to make a map but not quite getting it right. Is there some reason you're not just using an STL map?

Comment: I know that it looks like map, but as I said, I made such a simple example just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: It this what you are looking for, maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11

Comment: @Rakete1111. Something like that, but without boost dependencies.

Comment: The [range](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/) based answer isn't boost. It may even be in your standard library as `std::experimental::ranges`

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your trying to iterate through a class that doesn't have any kind of abstraction. What I mean is that you can only iterate through it if you "*make it*" a vector, or a different data structure that you could iterate through.

```
class Simple : public vector<std::pair<std::size_t, int>> { /*...*/ };
```

Once you declare a `class` with such syntax you would be able to handle it as a vector of pairs. You will have the advantage of declaring your own custom methods as well.

You can now:

```
Simple simple;
simple.push_back({10, 100});
for (auto element : simple) {
    std::cout << element.first << " " << element.second << std::endl;
}
```

I recommend you some [reading](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes) in this kind of implementations. Sometimes it can save a lot of work! And you know what they say, why to reinvent the wheel?

Remember that the method [at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/)(10) will return the element on position **10** of your vector. In your example you are trying to read from an `out_of_range` position.

Maybe you're interested in `map`, which contains a `key` and a `value`. From your example, it doesn't seem that you are trying to keep your data structure sorted. If you are, you can use a `map` instead of an   `unordered_map`. You can retrieve a value from a key by using the `find` method:

```
#include <unordered_map>

/* ... */

unordered_map<std::size_t, int> simple;    
simple.insert({10, 100});

auto it = simple.find(10);
if (it != simple.end()) {
    std::cout << "Found value from key: " << *it << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Your map doesn't contain such key!" << std::endl;
}
```

Notice that a `map` does not allow multiple keys with the same value. But a [multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/) does.

Comment: Probably, I did not stress it too much, but my example is not about map, multimap etc. I provided an example just for illustration purposes. I could have three vectors or more inside my Simple class and if I knew how to get a pair from iterator, I could generalize it and return a tuple. So, my question is purely about iterator.