# Type of index to iterate of vectors of different types

Tags: c++, vector, types

Given two vectors of different types but same length, what should be the type of the index to iterate over both in sync?

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"foo", "bar"};
    std::vector<double> values = {42, 314};

    std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0;
    std::vector<double>::size_type j = 0;

    while (i < words.size() && j < values.size()) {
        std::string w = words[i];
        double v = values[j];
        // do something with w and v
        ++i;
        ++j;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I wanted to use a single index, say `i`, to iterate over both `words` and `values`, what should be its type? Should it be `size_t`?

Comment: OT: you probably don't want to copy `words[i]` on each iteration.

Comment: @LogicStuff thanks, it was just to exemplify the indexing of `words` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types may or may not be the same, it is implementation dependent. Generally speaking, `std::vector::size_type` is almost always `std::size_t`, but this is not required by the standard. In any case, consider using iterators:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() // no need for (void) in C++
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = {"foo", "bar"};
    std::vector values = {42.0, 314.0}; // No need for <double> with C++17

    auto wit = words.cbegin(), wend = words.cend();
    auto vit = values.cbegin(), vend = values.cend();

    while (wit != wend && vit != vend) {
        std::string w = *wit++;
        double v = *vit++;
        // do something with w and v
    }
}
```

Iterators make it easier to use algorithms later on if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The member type alias `size_type` of `std::vector` is independent of the template parameters and is generally `std::size_t` (and cannot be/does not make sense to be bigger), so yes.

But there are [other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11) to iterating over multiple ranges.

Comment: "independent of the template parameters". That's untrue. It is dependent on the `Allocator`.

Comment: @geza After checking the standard, it falls under *implementation defined*, and that neither mandates nor forbids this dependency. So I don't know whether and how to fix that statement of mine...

Comment: This is wrong... No where in the standard it is said that `size_type` is independent of the template arguments and it is allowed to be dependent.

Comment: Hmm. I read this somewhere, maybe this is wrong. But still, it is worse now, because `size_type` can be anything. Even, it can be dependent on template parameters.