# Range based for loops without using std libraries

Tags: for-loop, c++11, arduino

I am working on an arduino project where I need to do the same task for a number of digital outputs. Since the arduino compiler supports C++11, I would like to use range-based for loops to have more readable code. However, as far as I know, on arduino there is no access to the `std` libraries that one would usually use in this case (correct me, if I'm wrong here). So my question is, whether there are good approaches to use range-based for loops without the `std` libraries. My (simplified) working code looks as follows:

```
static const byte OUTPUT_GROUP1[] = {4};
static const byte OUTPUT_GROUP2[] = {5, 6, 7};
static const byte *OUTPUTS[] = {OUTPUT_GROUP1, OUTPUT_GROUP2};

static const uint32_t MILLIS_GROUP1[] = {1000};
static const uint32_t MILLIS_GROUP2[] = {5000, 2000, 3000};
static const uint32_t *MILLIS[] = {MILLIS_GROUP1, MILLIS_GROUP2};

static const size_t GROUP_SIZES[] = {1, 3};

void loop() {
    for (size_t group = 0; group < 2; ++group) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < GROUP_SIZES[group]; ++i) {
            digitalWrite(OUTPUTS[group][i], HIGH);
            delay(MILLIS[group][i]);
            digitalWrite(OUTPUTS[group][i], LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

So there are two groups of outputs that I would like to keep apart. My main goal is to get rid of the variable `GROUP_SIZES`, since the number of outputs per group may change and forgetting about updating `GROUP_SIZES` is a source of error. For that I need to achieve two things. Firstly, I need to loop over nested lists, which usually I might solve using a `std::vector`. Secondly, I need to loop over two ranges simultaneously, to also access the millis to delay. This could be [done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8511035/5804088) using `std` or `boost`. However, on arduino it seems that there is no easy approach without coding a lot of magic myself. Is there an easy way to get this working?

Comment: Sorry but... what's the problem if you can't use the standard library. Range based for loop are a new (in C++11) language feature, not part of the standard library.

Comment: Because I don't know how to rewrite my code to make it use range-based for loops without the standard library. I know how to write such a loop over a single const array, but I have nested const arrays and the usual advice for this scenario is to use ``std::vector``. Also, I need to iterate over two arrays simulateously and again, the approach to do that is to use ``std`` or ``boost``. When those libraries are not there, it appears that range-based for loops are rather limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The code example in this answer only works if you compile in C++17 mode - see* how-to *at the end of the answer*

---

First, I recommend restructuring the data slightly. You have an output *pin* and an accociated *millis* time that you now store in separate arrays. I'd put them in a `struct`:

```cpp
struct Output {
    byte pin;
    uint32_t ms;
};
```

You also need a container that can store  objects and that has the `begin()` and `end()` member functions. I've put together an embryo, `staticvector`, which is sort of the worst of `std::vector` and  `std::array` combined - but it's simple. The reason I didn't make it more like a `std::array` is that it should be able to store arrays of `staticvector`s of different sizes. The reason for not making it more like `std::vector` is because it requires a lot more code.

To make it easier to follow I've copied a few of the possible implementations of some standard templates from https://cppreference.com/ and put them in a namespace of their own. You can read about the templates on https://cppreference.com/ if they are unfamiliar.

```cpp
namespace xyz {
template<class T> struct remove_reference      {using type = T;};
template<class T> struct remove_reference<T&>  {using type = T;};
template<class T> struct remove_reference<T&&> {using type = T;};
template<class T>
using remove_reference_t = typename remove_reference<T>::type;

template<class T>
constexpr T&&  forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept { return static_cast<T&&>(t); }
template<class T>
constexpr T&&  forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept { return static_cast<T&&>(t); }

template<class T>
constexpr remove_reference_t<T>&&  move(T&& t) noexcept {
    return static_cast<remove_reference_t<T>&&>(t);
}

template<class T, class U = T>
constexpr T exchange(T& obj, U&& new_value) {
    T old_value = move(obj);
    obj = forward<U>(new_value);
    return old_value;
}
} // namespace xyz
```

With those helper templates, the actual container could look like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
class staticvector {
private:
    size_t len = 0;
    T* data = nullptr;

public:
    // a constructor taking one or more T's and storing them in "data"
    template<class U, class... V>
    constexpr staticvector(U&& u, V&&... vs) :
        len(sizeof...(V) + 1),
        data{new T[sizeof...(V) + 1]{xyz::forward<U>(u), xyz::forward<V>(vs)...}}
    {}

    // copy constructor
    staticvector(const staticvector& rhs) :
        len(rhs.len),
        data(new T[len])
    {
        auto rhs_it = rhs.data;
        for(auto it = data, end = data + len; it != end; ++it, ++rhs_it) {
            *it = *rhs_it;
        }
    }

    // move constructor
    staticvector(staticvector&& rhs) noexcept :
        len(rhs.len), data(xyz::exchange(rhs.data, nullptr))
    {}

    // implement this if you wish
    staticvector& operator=(const staticvector&) = delete; // copy assignment
    
    // move assignment
    staticvector& operator=(staticvector&& rhs) noexcept {
        len = rhs.len;
        // this could use `std::swap(data, rhs.data)`
        auto *tmp = data;        
        data = rhs.data;
        rhs.data = tmp;
    }

    ~staticvector() { delete[] data; } // destructor

    size_t size() const { return len; }

    // subscript operator
    const T& operator[](size_t idx) const { return data[idx]; }
    T& operator[](size_t idx) { return data[idx]; }
    
    // iterator support
    using const_iterator = const T*;
    using iterator = T*;

    const_iterator cbegin() const { return data; }
    const_iterator cend() const { return data + len; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return cbegin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return cend(); }
    iterator begin() { return data; }
    iterator end() { return data + len; } 
};
```

Now you can create a `staticvector` containing `Output` objects and also a container containing such containers.

```
using OutputGroup = staticvector<Output>; // a convenience alias

// All your arrays put into a container of containers
static const staticvector<OutputGroup> OUTPUTS{
    OutputGroup{Output{4, 1000}},
    OutputGroup{Output{5, 5000}, Output{6, 2000}, Output{7, 3000}}
};

void loop() {

    // Two range-based for loops:
    for (const OutputGroup& group : OUTPUTS) {

        // structured bindings from each Output object in `group`
        for (auto[pin, ms] : group) {
            digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
            delay(ms);
            digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Evq7Enf8e)

---

#### Using C++17 in Arduino projects

Current Arduino IDE uses `g++ 7.3.0` and supports C++17 - but it's a bit messy to set it up.

- Find and edit `platform.txt` - I found it in `<installation_directory>/hardware/avr/1.8.3` but it may vary.
- Find the line that starts with `compiler.cpp.flags=`
- Change `-std=gnu++11` to `-std=gnu++17` on that line.

**Important note:** Programs using `delete[]` (like the above) will fail to *link* in C++17 mode because the arduino library doesn't include `operator delete[](void* ptr, size_t)`, even in the Arduino IDE 2.0-beta.

The current workaround seems to be to add your own to the project:

```
void operator delete[](void* ptr, size_t) noexcept { free(ptr); }
```

With the above fixes, the above program compiled for Uno with these stats:

```
Sketch uses 2052 bytes (6%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 43 bytes (2%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2005 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very extensive answer. The punchline is, however, that you need some datatype that defines ``begin()`` and ``end()``, correct? My point is that all lengths are known at compile time such that in principle there should be no need for an extra variable ``len``. But as soon as I am dealing with not a single, but nested const arrays, there just seems to be no way to make the compiler figure it out on its own, right? Apart from that, I must say that I don't understand all the template magic. Can you give me a pointer, where to read, to understand your code better?

Comment: @ranguwud "_you need some datatype that defines begin() and end(), correct?_" - No, bare C arrays can be used too ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ko85sEnGs)), but it's very hard to organize arrays of arrays with different lenghts using C arrays.