# Can we use C++ standard algorithm like std::mismatch instead of for loop for iterating over two equal length sequences?

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

Consider two vectors:

```
vector<int> A = {1, 4, 3};
vector<int> B = {5, 7, 1};
```

It's given both vectors are of equal length.
If I need to use element by element at each index and perform an operation, say counting number of indices with absolute difference less than or equal to a given value `3`.

Ideally, a for loop based implementation looks like this:

```
int cnt{0};
for(int i{0}; i < 3; i++)
        if(abs(A[i] - B[i]) <= 3)
            cnt++;    
}
```

However, I'm tempted to use a standard function like `std::mismatch` to perform the same.

```
int cnt{ 0 };
auto count_close_ones = [&](int const &a, int const &b) {
  if (abs(a - b) <= 3)
    cnt++;

  return true;
};
std::mismatch(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), count_close_ones);
```

Is it recommended? On one hand, I'm using a standard library function, so less prone to errors. On the other hand, the name `mismatch` may be misleading.
This question is not specific to `std::mistmatch`, it's just an example. I use `std::adjacent_find` too in the same way to iterate over pair of elements in same vector instead of two for loops.

Is it generally advisable?

Comment: imho if you use the standard algoritm merely to facilitate its loop, and basically any other algorithm that iterates two ranges can be used then there is no benefit of using the algorithm. The question is opinion based.

Comment: with a zipped iterator you can use `std::count_if`

Comment: What is a zipped iterator? Can you please provide a reference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511035/sequence-zip-function-for-c11 though with ranges there might be something available that isnt in those answers

Comment: Since C++23, there is ```std::ranges::zip_view```. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view