# If we have ranges::zip and views::transform, why do we need ranges::zip_transform?

Tags: c++, tuples, idioms, std-ranges

In C++23, the ranges (sub)library has gained [`std::ranges::zip`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view), which zips multiple ranges into a single range of `std::tuple`'s (or pairs). This is nice, and precludes requiring implementing this ourselves, using `boost::zip_iterator` or resorting to [this kind of a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70482642/1593077)<sup>*</sup>.

However, we also get `std::ranges::zip_transform`. Why do we need it? After all , we can apply a [`ranges::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) to a zipped range, can't we? So, isn't `zip_transform` redundant?

---

* - that hack works well in C++11, and doesn't require tens of thousands of lines of code with concepts...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If, in C++, the concepts of "the ordered parameters of a function" and "a tuple" were identical or easily interchangeable, then you would be right.

... unfortunately, that is not the case. The difference is that [`std::ranges::zip_transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_transform_view) cuts out the middle-man: Instead of constructing an `std::tuple` with each iterator advance and passing it to the transform function, references to the range elements themselves are passed to the function!

So, instead of writing something like:

```
auto add = [](std::tuple t) { 
    return std::get<0>(t) + std::get<1>(t) + std::get<2>(t); 
};
auto elementwise_sum = 
    std::views::zip(v1, v2, v3) | std::views::transform(add);
```

we can write, instead:

```
auto add = [](auto a, auto b, auto c) { return a + b + c; };
auto elementwise_sum = std::views::zip_transform(add, v1, v2, v3);
```

which I'm sure you'll agree is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what ***@einpoklum*** has explained about `zip_transform`, it is also worth noting that `zip_transform` will always forward each elements in a zipped result to the function. Which means it cannot be used as a drop-in replacement for `zip | transform`:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
auto func = [](std::tuple<int, int> t){ return double{}; };

views::zip(v1, v2) | views::transform(func); // ok

// views::zip_transform(func, v1, v2); // this will not work
```

The second one will not work because it **must** receive a function that takes 2 parameters.

---

Sidenote, there are also `views::adjacent`/`views::adjacent_transform`, and their `pairwise` specializations that behaves similar to `zip`/`zip_transform`.

Comment: Why should the zip_transform work in your code snippet? Tuples don't get magically constructed. If I just have `func`, I can't call `func(12, 34)` after all.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm unsure what you were asking. It clearly commented that it wouldn't work in my snippet

Comment: I'm asking what the motivation is for adding the line which doesn't work; it hints that one might have expected it to work, but it doesn't even though it might have.

Comment: @einpoklum The motivation is that based on the title of the question, one might expect `zip_transform(func, v1, v2)` be the shorthand/drop-in replacement for `zip(v1, v2) | transform(func)`, which is not true, which is what I was trying to demonstrate with my code. And since you already gave the correct way of using `zip_transform` in your answer, I didn't add that information in mine.