# c++: use boost range transformed adaptor with binary function

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, range, boost-range

Suppose I have two std::vectors x and y and a binary function F. I would like to create a new object z (not necessarily a vector), with the property that the ith elemenent of z will be the application of F to the ith elements of x and y. For the time being I use

```
boost::range::transform(x, y, z.begin(), F)
```

which of course requires memory allocation for z. My goal however is to avoid this memory allocation and have the transformation lazy evaluated, similarly to what boost::adaptors::transformed does with unary functions. In other words, the type of z would be some type of boost::range. Is there any easy way to do this or would I have to write my own range class? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @maverik: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that will not achieve my goal since memory would still need to be allocated for z (this time sequentially).

Comment: Even if one could achieve lazy evaluation, how do you imagine avoiding memory allocation when the vector size is unknown at compile time? I can only think of reserving enough memory once instead of sequentially; and depending on the context, one could leverage `alloca()`. Are those two possibilities an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Boost.Range does not provide a `zip_range` that can zip `x` and `y` as the inputfor your `transform`. So you need to write one yourself, e.g. using `make_iterator_range` and `zip_iterator` (from the Boost.Iterator library). See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553437/819272) for a code example.