# C++, range loop with multiple variables

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, iterator, range

There is the following type

```
 template <typename T>
 using TL = std::vector<T>;
```

How to create a multiple/based range loop over two variables

```
 TL <double> l1, l2;     
 for ( auto a:l1, auto b:l2)
```

instead of using

```
 TL::iterator = il1, il2;
 for (il1 = l1. begin(), il2=l2.begin();;)
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: You could use BOOST_FOREACH and [zip_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html)

Comment: There is no such thing in `C++`, anyway, If it was what would happen when one `vector` will be shorter than another? The best option is to use nested for-range loops.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552277/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-two-or-more-containers-simultaneously

Comment: @PcAF: No, such a thing may be easily constructed in C++, and nested for-range loops are not only not "the best option" but they won't even do what is being asked for.

Comment: @ Baum : Thanks, I missed the thread...

Comment: @LightnessRaceInOrbit I've just read linked question, first answers states that if their length is not the same it causes undefined behaviour  (in some specific version, I'm not sure about ofther versions). Nested loops will  be slow and redudant, I agree, I just made a ....(ehm.. (big mistake))