# Modifying two vectors of the same type in a for loop

Tags: c++, vector

I'd like to modify the values stored in two vectors of the same type T in the same loop.
For example, say I have two vectors of ints:

```
std::vector<int> student_ids;   
std::vector<int> teacher_ids;
```

Now I'd like to loop through these two vectors at the same time, and simply show each value for now. For instance:

```
for(int id : student_ids, teacher_ids)
{
    std::cout << id << "\n";
}
```

How would I be able to achieve that?

Comment: Use simple `for` without range-based loop

Comment: use good ol' for loop or boost::zip

Comment: You can't, you have to use some other method (two loops? looping using indexes?)

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552277/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-two-or-more-containers-simultaneously

Comment: Why do you want this? What is the advantage of a single loop?

Comment: @NathanOliver That one is about vectors of the same length. I do not see that requirement here.

Comment: hence the related first and me not closing the Q.

Comment: @Bernhard The class has two vectors of structures and I can't really change the way it works, so I have to loop through the two vectors at once and I'm trying to keep it as clean as possible.

Comment: consider restructuring your data so that there is 1 vector which contains pairs of IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way you can iterate the two vectors in one loop but keep in mind to **check for bounds if the sizes of the two vectors are not same**.

```
std::vector <int>::iterator it1 = student_ids.begin();
std::vector <int>::iterator it2 = teacher_ids.begin();

while(it1 != student_ids.end() || it2 != teacher_ids.end()) {
    if(it1 != student_ids.end()) {
        std::cout << "Student: " << *it1 << std::endl;
        ++it1;
    }
    if(it2 != teacher_ids.end()) {
        std::cout << "Teacher: " << *it2 << std::endl;
        ++it2;
    }
}
```

Else, if you are sure that the **size of both the vectors are same**, just replace the `||` with `&&` and you can do away the `if` conditions within the loops like this:

```
for(; it1 != student_ids.end() && it2 != teacher_ids.end(); ++it1, ++it2) {
    std::cout << "Student: " << *it1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Teacher: " << *it2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I'm looking for!  I will probably be implementing it this way now.

Comment: @Jarod42 Changed the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access **simultaneously** in your loop body both vectors, the only way is a normal for:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<std::max(student_ids.size(),teacher_ids.size()); i++) {
    if (i<student_ids.size())   // are there still students ? 
       cout << student_ids[i];
    cout <<" : ";
    if (i<teacher_ids.size())   // are there still teachers ? 
       cout << teacher_ids[i];
    cout<<endl;
}
```

But I understand from your example that you are looking for iterating through both vectors **sequentially** and that you're looking for a convenient way to avoid redundant code.

If you don't want to write two loops one after the other because of a very complex body, and if you don't want to put this body into a function because of access to a lot of local variables make a lambda out of it:

```
auto f = [&](int& id) {  cout << id<<endl; };  // could be more complex !   
for_each(student_ids.begin(), student_ids.end(), f); 
for_each(teacher_ids.begin(), teacher_ids.end(), f);
```

Alternatively you could use a temporary merged vector to iterate over:

```
auto temp(student_ids); 
copy(teacher_ids.begin(), teacher_ids.end(), back_inserter(temp)); 
for (auto &id : temp )
   cout << id<<endl;
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/VcAuJP)

Answer (score 0):

```
auto studentIterator = student_ids.begin();
auto teacherIterator = teacher_ids.begin();
auto studentIteratorEnd = student_ids.end(); // for tiny performance
auto teacherIteratorEnd = teacher_ids.end(); // the same

while (true)
{
  if (studentIterator != studentIteratorEnd)
  {
    std::cout << *studentIterator << std::endl;
    ++studentIterator;
  }
  if (teacherIterator != teacherIteratorEnd)
  {
    std::cout << *teacherIterator << std::endl;
    ++teacherIterator;
  }
  if (studentIterator == studentIteratorEnd && teacherIterator == teacherIteratorEnd)
    break;
}
```