# How to keep in sync looping over 2 maps?

Tags: c++, iterator, compare, std

how to loop in sync over 2 maps?
it could be that either map1 or map2 contains more keys.
how do i set the preference? and increment the corresponding iterator?

example values of 2 maps:

```
4 7 10 11 12 13 14 
3 4 7 8 10 11 12 13 14
```

map1 doesn't contain a '3'

[What's the best way to iterate over two or more containers simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552277/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-two-or-more-containers-simultaneously)

```
std::map<int, int> map1;
std::map<int, int> map2;
auto itA = begin(map1);
auto itB = begin(map2);

while(itA != end(map1) || itB != end(map2))
{
    if(itA != end(map1))
    {
        ++itA;
    }
    if(itB != end(map2))
    {
        ++itB;
    }
}
```

using this code would result that you try yo compare 2 unequal numbers / values.
so you must halt incrementing one or the other iterator until both value are equal.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlanBirtles one thing: is to find those number that don't occur in either map.

Comment: So, the linked topic does not answer your question?

Comment: The keys or the values that aren't in both?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, the keys, "auto it = map1.find([value]);", is easy, but the right 'OR' statement that determines witch iterator of the above loop code to increment until the meet up.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, n.v.m. i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer:

```
if(map1.first == map2.first){
    if(itA != end(map1)){
        ++itA;
    }
    if(itB != end(map2)){
        ++itB;
    }
}
else if(map1.first < map2.first){
    if(itA != end(map1)){
        ++itA;
    }
}
else if(map1.first > map2.first){
    if(itB != end(map2)){
        ++itB;
    }
}
```

Comment: could remove the first `if` block and change the `else if`s to `if <=` and `if >=`