# Zip lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-zip

I am trying to learn how to "zip" lists. To this end, I have a program, where at a particular point, I do the following:

```
x1, x2, x3 = stuff.calculations(withdataa)
```

This gives me three lists, `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`, each of, say, size 20.

Now, I do:

```
zipall = zip(x1, x2, x3)
```

However, when I do:

```
print "len of zipall %s" % len(zipall)
```

I get 20, which is not what I expected. I expected three. I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `zip` to do? Why should you have three lists - what would they look like?

Comment: zip returns a list of tuples.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

When you `zip()` together three lists containing 20 elements each, the result has twenty elements. Each element is a three-tuple.

See for yourself:

```
In [1]: a = b = c = range(20)

In [2]: zip(a, b, c)
Out[2]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 1),
 ...
 (17, 17, 17),
 (18, 18, 18),
 (19, 19, 19)]
```

To find out how many elements each tuple contains, you could examine the length of the first element:

```
In [3]: result = zip(a, b, c)

In [4]: len(result[0])
Out[4]: 3
```

Of course, this won't work if the lists were empty to start with.

Comment: len(result[0]) wont work. 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @GilbertS in Python 2 `zip` returned a list. In Python 3 it is an iterator

Comment: @GilbertS in Python 3 use `list(zip(a, b, c))` to get the Python 2 behaviour.

Answer (score 74):

`zip` takes a bunch of lists likes

```
a: a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7...
b: b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7...
c: c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7...
```

and "zips" them into one list whose entries are 3-tuples `(ai, bi, ci)`. Imagine drawing a zipper horizontally from left to right.

Comment: @Sigur: ["Convert tuple to list and back
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296643/convert-tuple-to-list-and-back)

Comment: Does this require the lists to have the same size?

Answer (score 43):

In Python 2.7 this might have worked fine:

```
>>> a = b = c = range(20)
>>> zip(a, b, c)
```

But in Python 3.4 it should be (otherwise, the result will be something like `<zip object at 0x00000256124E7DC8>`):

```
>>> a = b = c = range(20)
>>> list(zip(a, b, c))
```

Answer (score 30):

`zip` creates a new list, filled with tuples containing elements from the iterable arguments:

```
>>> zip ([1,2],[3,4])
[(1,3), (2,4)]
```

I expect what you try to so is create a tuple where each element is a list.

Answer (score 23):

In **Python 3** `zip` returns an iterator instead and needs to be passed to a list function to get the zipped tuples:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]; y = ['a','b','c']
z = zip(x, y)
z = list(z)
print(z)
>>> [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Then to `unzip` them back just conjugate the zipped iterator:

```
x_back, y_back = zip(*z)
print(x_back); print(y_back)
>>> (1, 2, 3)
>>> ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

If the original form of list is needed instead of tuples:

```
x_back, y_back = zip(*z)
print(list(x_back)); print(list(y_back))
>>> [1,2,3]
>>> ['a','b','c']
```

Comment: The question tag states Python 2.7; this is for Python 3. Besides, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29980021/9769953) already mentions this.

Comment: @9769953 This answer is useful I was google zip lists on python, not python 2.7.

Answer (score 15):

Source: [My Blog Post (better formatting)](https://medium.com/@PrintSupWorld/unzipping-python-2-340701d300a6)

**Example**

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
letters = 'abcd'

zip(numbers, letters)
# [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

### **Input**

Zero or more iterables [1] (ex. list, string, tuple, dictionary)

### **Output** (list)

> 1st tuple = (element_1 of numbers, element_1 of letters)
>
> 2nd tuple = (e_2 numbers, e_2 letters)
>
> …
>
> n-th tuple = (e_n numbers, e_n letters)

1. List of n tuples: n is the length of the shortest argument (input)

   - len(numbers) == 3 < len(letters) == 4 → short= 3 → return 3 tuples
2. Length each tuple = # of args (tuple takes an element from each arg)

   - args = (numbers,letters); len(args) == 2 → tuple with 2 elements
3. `i`th tuple = (element_i arg1, element_i arg2…, element_i arg`n`)

### **Edge Cases**

1) Empty String: len(str)= 0 = no tuples

2) Single String: len(str) == 2 tuples with len(args) == 1 element(s)

```
zip()
# []
zip('')
# []
zip('hi')
# [('h',), ('i',)]
```

---

### **Zip in Action!**

**1. Build a dictionary [2] out of two lists**

```
keys = ["drink","band","food"]
values = ["La Croix", "Daft Punk", "Sushi"]

my_favorite = dict( zip(keys, values) )

my_favorite["drink"]
# 'La Croix'

my_faves = dict()
for i in range(len(keys)):
    my_faves[keys[i]] = values[i]
```

- `zip` is an elegant, clear, & concise solution

**2. Print columns in a table**

"*" [3] is called "unpacking": `f(*[arg1,arg2,arg3]) == f(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

```
student_grades = [
[   'Morty'  ,  1   ,  "B"  ],
[   'Rick'   ,  4   ,  "A"  ],
[   'Jerry'  ,  3   ,  "M"  ],
[  'Kramer'  ,  0   ,  "F"  ],
]

row_1 = student_grades[0]
print row_1
# ['Morty', 1, 'B']

columns = zip(*student_grades)
names = columns[0]
print names
# ('Morty', 'Rick', 'Jerry', 'Kramer')
```

---

### Extra Credit: Unzipping

`zip(*args)` is called “unzipping” because it has the inverse effect of `zip`

```
numbers = (1,2,3)
letters = ('a','b','c')

zipped = zip(numbers, letters)
print zipped
# [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

unzipped = zip(*zipped)
print unzipped
# [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

- `unzipped`: tuple_1 = e1 of each zipped tuple. tuple_2 = e2 of each `zipped`

---

### Footnotes

1. An object capable of returning its members one at a time (ex. list [1,2,3], string 'I like codin', tuple (1,2,3), dictionary {'a':1, 'b':2})
2. {key1:value1, key2:value2...}
3. “Unpacking” (*)

`*` Code:

```
# foo - function, returns sum of two arguments
def foo(x,y):
    return x + y
print foo(3,4)
# 7

numbers = [1,2]
print foo(numbers)
# TypeError: foo() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

print foo(*numbers)
# 3
```

`*` took `numbers` (1 arg) and “unpacked” its’ 2 elements into 2 args

Answer (score 13):

Basically the zip function works on lists, tuples and dictionaries in Python.
If you are using IPython then just type zip? And check what zip() is about.

If you are not using IPython then just install it: "pip install ipython"

For lists

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['p', 'q', 'r']
zip(a, b)
```

The output is `[('a', 'p'), ('b', 'q'), ('c', 'r')`

For dictionary:

```
c = {'gaurav':'waghs', 'nilesh':'kashid', 'ramesh':'sawant', 'anu':'raje'}
d = {'amit':'wagh', 'swapnil':'dalavi', 'anish':'mane', 'raghu':'rokda'}
zip(c, d)
```

The output is:

```
[('gaurav', 'amit'),
 ('nilesh', 'swapnil'),
 ('ramesh', 'anish'),
 ('anu', 'raghu')]
```

Comment: zip(c,d) is performing zip(list(c), list(d))

Answer (score 9):

For the completeness's sake.

When zipped lists' lengths are not equal.
The result list's length will become the shortest one without any error occurred

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = ["2", 3]
>>> zip(a,b)
[(1, '2')]
```

Answer (score 8):

It's worth adding here as it is such a highly ranking question on zip. `zip` is great, idiomatic Python - but it doesn't scale very well at all for large lists.

Instead of:

```
books = ['AAAAAAA', 'BAAAAAAA', ... , 'ZZZZZZZ']
words = [345, 567, ... , 672]

for book, word in zip(books, words):
   print('{}: {}'.format(book, word))
```

Use `izip`. For modern processing, it stores it in L1 Cache memory and is far more performant for larger lists. Use it as simply as adding an `i`:

```
for book, word in izip(books, words):
   print('{}: {}'.format(book, word))
```

Comment: While this post is informative, it doesn't actually answer the OP's question.