# what is the difference between [(a,b),(c,d)] and [[a,b],[c,d]] and how can I turn one into another in python?

Tags: python, list

So my question is exactly defined in the title. That is, what is the difference between

```
 [(a,b),(c,d)]
```

and

```
 [[a,b],[c,d]]
```

and how I can turn one into another in Python.

This question is partly duplicate but the main part is how to turn one into another which in not duplicate.

Comment: And how I can turn one into another?

Comment: Only 1/2 of his question is duplicate to that.

Comment: Since, I cannot answer on a closed question, here is the answer to the second half of your question: A Simple list comprehension should suffice. `a = [(a,b),(c,d)]`  `b = [list(x) for x in a]`  `c = [[a,b],[c,d]]`  `d = [tuple(x) for x in c]`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A list is that which encloses its contents in a bracket `[]`.

A tuple is that which encloses its contents in a parentheses `()`.

Lists are mutable (changeable); tuples are not.

Turning a list into a tuple is possible:

Changing a tuple to list:

`list(myTuple)`

Changing list to tuple:

`tuple(myList)`

Comment: and how I can turn one into another in Python.

Comment: `list` function should do it

Comment: Downvoted because this answer is much less comprehensive than those on the marked duplicate.

Comment: @user25064 I've edited my answer. Did it help?

Comment: You guys are very interesting. Look at the title of the question and it is obvious that I did not know even what to search for and this was my main problem. How should I even know that this question was duplicate without knowing the terms?

Comment: @HimanUCC A google search for "list to tuple and back" brings [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296643/convert-tuple-to-list-and-back). Did my answer resolve your question? If it helped, make sure to click the up-arrow and if it resolved it, click the checkmark.

Comment: @jossie Calderon If I knew it was called "tuple", why should I even ask the question?

Comment: @HimanUCC By Google searching "the difference between brackets and parentheses in python".

Comment: if the downvotes bother you @HimanUCC you can just remove your question.  Hopefully the duplicate and the discussion helped you out.  Also, try the python.org tutorial.. Lots of basic stuff there