# Python - Function argument with a comma

Tags: python, arrays, function

I want to have an argument in a function that fills an array with multiple strings, so that i have

```
def Test(colors):
     colorarray = [colors]
```

which i can fill with

```
Test(red,blue)
```

but i always get either the `takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` error or the single strings do not get accepted (e.g. TurtleColor(Color[i]) tells me `"bad color string: "red","blue"`)

i know i can pass the strings as seperate arguments, but i kind of want to avoid having that many different arguments.

Comment: You say `TurtleColor(Color[i])` throws a `bad color string: "red","blue"` error, but what _are_ `TurtleColor` and `Color` and `i`?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296643/convert-tuple-to-list-and-back) if you need to convert the `*args` tuple to a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read input arguments as a list

```
   def Test(*colors):
         colorarray = [*colors]
         print(colorarray)

    Test('red','blue')
```

Comment: That should work, what do i do if i have a second argument?
e.g.
def Test(*colors,size):

and entering Test('red','blue',100) didnt work - told me it required a keyword-only argument: 'size'


          EDIT: Test('red','blue',size=100) does work. unsatisfying though, wonder if i can spare that "size=" with some syntax

Comment: @FlyingThunder: If the size is always there just change the order! `Test(size,*colors)`

Comment: so the list has to come last, that shouldnt be a problem - i hope i dont stumble across a case where i have to input multiple lists then. thanks for quick advice

Comment: `list(colors)` would be more readable and more backwards compatible than `[*colors]`.

Comment: Aran is right, an alternative is to input colors as a single list argument that keeps your code cleaner (specially if you have multiple arguments). However instead of a list (which is mutable) I suggest to use tuples:
`def Test(colors,size)`, and call it `Test(('red','blue'),100)`

Comment: that seems to be working too and looks better, thanks for the tip!