# I want to get all combination of a list in form of a list of list using combinations method of itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I tried this

```
import itertools
a=[10, 1 ,2, 7, 6, 1, 5]
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for s in itertools.combinations(a,i):
        if s not in b:
            b.append(s)
print(b)
```

I am getting desired output in form of tuple. I want output as below:

```
[[10],[1],...[10,1],...[10,1,2]....]
```

Comment: `b.append(list(s))`, then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert tuple to list and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296643/convert-tuple-to-list-and-back)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: this will not work, since the `s in b` check will work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem good point, then maybe `for s in map(list, itertools...):`.

Comment: `b = list(map(list,b))` before printing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's a good way to combinate through a set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/whats-a-good-way-to-combinate-through-a-set)

Comment: This is a duplicate, as the OP's looking for the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of an iterable. There is a [Python recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#recipes) for exactly this on the `itertools` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most functions in `itertools` produce `tuple`s, but the good news is that a tuple is an iterable, and you can use `list(..)` with an iterable to convert the iterable to a list.

We can thus for example `map` the results of the itertools, like:

```
from itertools import combinations

a=[10, 1 ,2, 7, 6, 1, 5]
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for s in map(list, combinations(a,i)):
        if s not in b:
            b.append(s)
print(b)
```

But nevertheless this is still not a good idea. A membership check of a list, runs in linear time. Since there are an exponential number of combinations, this means that it will start running in *O((n!)<sup>2</sup>)* time, with *n* the number of elements, which is typically very slow.

A faster way to do this, is using a `set` concurrently, that stores the elements, and then each time check membership of the tuple (a `set` can not contain `list`s, since `list`s are unhashable), in case the membership fails, we add it to `b` as a list:

```
from itertools import combinations

a=[10, 1 ,2, 7, 6, 1, 5]
b=[]
seen = set()

for i in range(len(a)):
    for s in combinations(a,i):
        if s not in seen:
            seen.add(s)
            b.append(list(s))
print(b)
```