# How to convert this tuple to array python

Tags: python

This one outputs tuple, but I want it to convert to array so I can access each element in the array to my main function. here is the code:

```
def numbers():
    db = getDB();
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT mobile_number FROM names"
    cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()

    for [x] in result:
        print(x)
```

Comment: `result = list(cur.fetchall())`

Comment: possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: list(result) is how to convert

Comment: "but I want it to convert to array so I can access each element in the array to my main function." I don't understand why you can't do that with a tuple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert tuple to list and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296643/convert-tuple-to-list-and-back)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple:

```
result = list(cur.fetchall())
```