# How to unpack single-item tuples in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this form of a list of lists:

```
[[('1st',), ('2nd',), ('5th',)], [('1st',)]]
```

I want to convert this to:

```
[['1st', '2nd', '5th'], ['1st']]
```

I tried this:

```
res = [list(ele) for ele in racer_placement for ele in ele]
```

But the result I got:

```
[['1st'], ['2nd'], ['5th'], ['1st']]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert tuple to list and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296643/convert-tuple-to-list-and-back)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need nested comprehensions (with [either a two layer loop in the inner comprehension, or use `chain.from_iterable` for flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/364696)). Example with two layer loop (avoids need for imports), see the linked question for other ways to flatten the inner `list` of `tuple`s:

```
>>> listolists = [[('1st',), ('2nd',), ('5th',)], [('1st',)]]
>>> [[x for tup in lst for x in tup] for lst in listolists]
[['1st', '2nd', '5th'], ['1st']]
```

Note that in this specific case of single element `tuple`s, you can avoid the more complicated flattening with just:

```
 >>> [[x for x, in lst] for lst in listolists]
```

per [the safest way of getting the only element from a single-element sequence in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33161448/364696).

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing to replace the contents of the first level of lists with a new list built from the first element of the tuples.

```
>>> racer_placement = [[('1st',), ('2nd',), ('5th',)], [('1st',)]]
>>> for elem in racer_placement:
...     elem[:] = [elem2[0] for elem2 in elem]
... 
>>> racer_placement
[['1st', '2nd', '5th'], ['1st']]
```

Since this is updating the inner list, any other reference to those lists would also see the change. That could be great or disasterous.

Answer (score 0):

```
List = [[('1st',), ('2nd',), ('5th',)], [('1st',)]]
Parentlist = [] 
Temp=[] 
for childlist in List:
     Temp=[] 
     for x in childlist
          Temp.Add(x[0]) 
     parentlist.Add(Temp)
```

This is untested.