# My iteration will only return the last item in my list, not return each item one at a time to pass to another function for use in a master list

Tags: python, list, loops, return

Beginner question: I am trying to iterate over the lists and return each item to send to another list. I can only get it to return the last item in each list- 4 & 'home'. What am I doing wrong?

```
def held():
    alist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    blist = ['bob', 'is','not', 'home']
    for event in range(0,3):   
        for item in alist:
            ide = item
            acc_id = int(ide)
        for item in blist:
            sev = item
            sever = str(sev)
    return acc_id, sever  
        
held()
```

Comment: You can only return one value. WHat exactly do you want to be the output of `help()`?

Comment: don't use help() as name of function in your program because there is a built-in help() function in python and defining custom one with same name might confuse others in future if they initially look at last line of code.

Comment: Then how can i pass the first item? I will then run the function again as required. Unless there is a better way?

Comment: @user16710824 why don't you try a list of tuples to return all at once.

Comment: The data has come from a pandas .tolist() funtion. Is that an option with this kind of output data? I am only very new at this.... Can you explain please? I think it sounds like what I am essentially trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement can only **get executed once** in a **method**. It will only return the last elements because, the program will at first loop through the list and then return the values (that will then equals the last value of the list while that was the las iteration executed).
If you want to return something like `[1, "bob", 2, "is"...]`, you could do something like :

```
array1 = [1, 3, 5]
array2= [2, 4, 6]
array3 = []
for index in range(0, len(array1)):
    array3.append(array1[index])
    array3.append(array2[index])
print(array3)
# Expexted output : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

As said in the comments by [Timus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14311263/timus), if you want `[(1, "bob"), (2, "is")...]` as output, you can do:

```
array1 = [1, 3, 5]
array2= [2, 4, 6]
array3 = list(zip(array1 , array2))
print(array3)
# Expected output : [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: The order ends up what I need, but I need each 'first item' in a list, then each 'second item' in a list within the array. Aiming for [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] ultimately. Does it make a difference if they are named as array or list?

Comment: @user16710824 Then use `list(zip(alist, blist))`

Comment: If I can then convert the tuples to lists this answers my question. Thanks

Comment: @user16710824 Apparently you can : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296643/convert-tuple-to-list-and-back