# wrong output while joining two lists in ipython

Tags: python, csv, ipython, file-writing

I have two lists - `list1` when printed looks like this:

```
[['KR', 'Alabama', 111], ['KR', 'Alabama', 909], ['KR', 'Alabama', 90], ['KR', 'Alabama', 10], ['KR', 'Arizona', 12], ['KR', 'Arizona', 10], ['KR', 'Arizona', 93], ['KR', 'Arizona', 98],....]
```

And `list2` when printed looks like this:

[11, 110, 108,....]

Now I want to join these two lists and write the result into a csv file so that output looks like this:

```
KR,Alabama,111,11
KR,Alabama,909,110
KR,Alabama,90,108
KR,Alabama,10,34
KR,Arizona,12,45
```

So basically the values of `list2` becomes the 4th column in csv file. I wrote this code in `ipython` but it produces output in wrong format and also does not write all the records in the file (last 26 records are not in the file):

```
final_list = zip(list1,list2)
print final_list

cdc_part1 = open("file1.csv", 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(cdc_part1, dialect='excel')

wr.writerows(final_list)
```

The output in file looks like:

```
"['KR', 'Alabama', 111]",11
"['KR', 'Alabama', 909]",110
"['KR', 'Alabama', 90]",108
"['KR', 'Alabama', 10]",34
"['KR', 'Arizona', 12]",45
```

As you can notice there `"` and `[]` around the `list1` item and strings in `list1` have `'` around them. How can I get the correct format of output and why last 26 records are not getting written to file?

**NOTE:** `list1`,`list2` as well as `final_list` that I am forming all are of same size (300) but yet in file I see only 274 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `list1` is a list of lists, performing `zip(list1, list2)` will end up with something like this:

```py
[(['KR', 'Alabama', 111], 11),
 (['KR', 'Alabama', 909], 110),
 (['KR', 'Alabama', 90], 108)]
```

So you'll need to add an extra step in there to add last element to the first list.

```py
final_list = [ a + [b] for a, b in zip(list1, list2) ]
```

This will get you,

```py
[['KR', 'Alabama', 111, 11],
 ['KR', 'Alabama', 909, 110],
 ['KR', 'Alabama', 90, 108]]
```

And that should output the CSV properly.

Comment: how do I remove `'` around strings?

Comment: @user2966197 The output I have is python's string representation of the list. The CSV library you're using should properly format the CSV file. You just have to change your line `final_list = ...` to the line above.

Comment: also I am using `ipython` for this and so my code which writes to a csv file, is there anything wrong to it that may result in last 26 records not getting written to file? Is there a better way to write to csv file in ipython?

Comment: @user2966197 I'm unsure of why you would be missing 26 records. I would investigate those records and see if there's some encoding problem that causes the csv module to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

You are using zip the wrong way, for more look here [zip lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python).
the problem is that zip joins elements in the input lists, here the element in the first list itself is a list so its joined to the elements in the second list. 
the correct way to do it is

```
for each in xrange(0, len(list1)):
    list1[each].append[list2[each]]
print list1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all in how `zip` works. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.

So `zip` expects each argument to be an iterable.  It will then create an iterable (in python2 a list) of tuples grabbing the ith element of each argument for the ith tuple.  So if you pass in a list of lists as the first argument and a list of strings as the second, your final items will each be a tuple where each first element is the inner list of `list1` and the second element is the corresponding indexed string from `list2`.

Instead, you want something like:

```
final_list = [list1[i] + [list2[i]] for i in \
     range(min(len(list1),len(list2)))]
```

As to why the last 26 records are not in the file, from the zip docs:

> The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted

So your `list2` has 26 fewer elements than `list1`. Rather than guess at what to add to the last 26 items from `list1`, it just doesn't include them in the result.

*Note:* Using `min()` in the new `final_list` formulation as above will result in the same short-circuiting behavior