# How do you write one element of multiple lists to a file before moving on to the next element?

Tags: python

I have multiple lists, for example,

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,7,8]
z = [9,10,11,12]
```

And I want to write one element of each list to a file.

The output I'm trying to get is `1 5 9 2 6 10 3 7 11 4 8 12`. So all the first elements, then all the second, and so forth.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your code please? Also, are you assuming all lists are the same size?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`zip(x, y, z)`? Have you tried search your question before asking?

Comment: I've tried nested for loops, but that doesn't work since it repeats it way too many times. Like `for i in range(len(x)): and for j in range(len(y)) and k in range(len(x))` Also, no the lists are not the same size (not necessarily)

Comment: `write_file.write(" ".join(x for tup in zip(x, y, z) for x in tup))`

Comment: Is there always 4 items per list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Zip` *and* convert each integer element to `string` so that you can join them:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,7,8]
z = [9,10,11,12]

g = " ".join(str(x) for t in zip(x, y, z) for x in t)
```

Write `g` to your file.

Excerpt on how [Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python) works:

> When you `zip()` together M lists containing N elements each, the
>   result has N elements. Each element is a M-tuple.

In other words, `zip(x,y,z)` changes your:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
[9,10,11,12]
```

to

```
[(1,5,9),(2,6,10),(3,7,11),(4,8,12)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I forgot I had to convert it to a string before joining it.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the ability to have three lists that might have different number of items in each one.

```
number = max(x.len(), y.len(),z.len())
count = 0
total = {}
while count < number:
     try:
           total.append(x[count])
     except:
           pass
     try:
           total.append(y[count])
     except:
           pass
     try:
           total.append(z[count])
     except:
           pass
     count += 1
print(' '.join(total))
```

Comment: Why not use `itertools.zip_longest()`?

Comment: because I'm not that educated.  I'll have to go dig it about.

Comment: Don't worry.  I didn't know about until this month :)

Comment: It is good that your solution can handle multiple lists with different number of items. However, if you just remove the try-catch and doing pre-check before adding the element, the solution would be a lot better

Comment: is it faster to run a If vs a try?  I always thought a try was faster.

Comment: `try` is OK, but `except` is not. If your lists contain different number of items, then it is expected that it will have many `excepts`

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have lists of equal lengths, you can use `zip_longest` (or `izip_longest` in python 2):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]  
y = [5, 6, 7, 8, 99]
z = [9, 10, 11, 12]  # short list

reordered = []
for elements in zip_longest(x, y, z):
    reordered.extend(elements)
```

Results in a list of:

> [1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11, 4, 8, 12, 1, 99, None]