# Python looping through multiple lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

I've this code:

```
for i in range(0, len(codiceCassExcel)):
count1step += 1
 for j in range(0, len(vwLinesToList)):
    if data_reg[i] == vwLinesToList[j][1]:
        if codiceCassExcel[i] == vwLinesToList[j][0]:
            #Gestione movimento diverso da 601 e non bolle nostre
            if tipo_mov[i] != 601 and len(vwLinesToList[j][7]) != 8:
                count2step += 1
                if ((int(qta_movimentata[i]) + int(vwLinesToList[j][4])) != 0) or ((int(-qta_movimentata[i]) + int(vwLinesToList[j][3])) != 0):
                    imballoColumnIn.append(vwLinesToList[j][0]),
                    dateColumnIn.append(vwLinesToList[j][1]),
                    absColumnIn.append(vwLinesToList[j][2]),
                    inColumnIn.append(vwLinesToList[j][3]),
                    outColumnIn.append(vwLinesToList[j][4]),
                    ddtColumnIn.append(vwLinesToList[j][7]),
                    wkColumnIn.append(vwLinesToList[j][8])
            elif vwLinesToList[j][7] == bolla_excel[i]:
                if ((int(qta_movimentata[i]) + int(vwLinesToList[j][4])) != 0) or (
                    (int(-qta_movimentata[i]) + int(vwLinesToList[j][3])) != 0):
                    imballoColumn.append(vwLinesToList[j][0]),
                    dateColumn.append(vwLinesToList[j][1]),
                    absColumn.append(vwLinesToList[j][2]),
                    inColumn.append(vwLinesToList[j][3]),
                    outColumn.append(vwLinesToList[j][4]),
                    ddtColumn.append(vwLinesToList[j][7]),
                    wkColumn.append(vwLinesToList[j][8])
```

I've 5 lists with hundred of items and a lists with similar items (vwLinesToLists). I want to check if:

```
firstListItem[i] and secondListItem[i](and so on...) is equal to
vwLinesToList[j][1],  vwLinesToList[j][2], vwLinesToList[j][3]
If it's true, check if nListItem - vwLinesToList[j][6] != 0:
append each vwLinesToList[item] to separate list
```

I need an hint about write my code without all this nested stuff.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you know about `zip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**zip**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) method to iterate over your lists. See [zip lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python) for code samples.

Also consider using of [izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) function which may be useful to...

Comment: Thank you! Sure the zip function Will help me!