# Plotting in numpy a graph using the two lowest eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, networkx

How do I use the eigenvectors corresponding to the two lowest eigenvalues (different from 0) as the x,y coordinates to plot the graph?

I have arrays of eigenvalues and eigenvectors from the laplacian of a graph of nodes. I want to do something similar to the following link that is in MATLAB, but in Python. Also, instead of just the Fielder vector, I also want the next vector larger than the Fielder as well:

https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/matlab-ex64540792-partition-graph-with-laplacian-matrix

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code you use to get the eigenvectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you've already got nodes in a list `nodelist` and two vectors `vec1` and `vec2` which are in the same order.

Networkx uses a dict (usually called `pos`) for which `pos[u]` is the (x,y) coordinates of the node `u`.

```
import networkx as nx

#your code here to define network and find the vectors.  
#Please edit a simple version of this code into your question so I can
#add it here.

pos = {node:(x,y) for node, x, y in zip(nodelist, vec1, vec2)}
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
```

In defining `pos`, I've used a [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python) and [zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python).