# Prompt to enter a name and then output the name that was entered along a score

Tags: python

I am writing a program for my intro CS class but I am a little stuck.
I have a designated list of names that correspond to a list of scores.
I am supposed to prompt the user to enter a name and then the program is supposed to output the name that was entered along with the corresponding score.
As I have it written now the program is printing the first name and score in the set regardless of the input. I have been stuck on this for a while, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have right now:

```
names=['Jim','Sarah','Jason','Lynne','Ginny','Joe','Susan'];
scores=['88','92','95','84','85','92','89'];
input("Please enter student's name:")
for i in range (0,7):                             
    print (input(names[i] + scores[i]));
```

Comment: You are utterly ignoring the input. What do you expect to happen? You need to *capture* the input in a variable and then *use* that variable in the remainder of the code. Also, having the `input` inside the print statement like that really makes no sense. Perhaps you could visit your instructor during their office hours?

Comment: Python doesn't use semi-colons, by the way.

Comment: @cricket_007 semicolons work (they separate statements) but of course not needed here.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Clarification = *as line-terminators* :)

Answer (score 0):

> the program is supposed to output the name that was entered

That'll be hard considering you aren't capturing the `input()` return value.

Try this (as an example)

```
name = input("Please enter student's name:")
print(name)
```

Then, you next task is to check (in your loop) when `name == <a name in the list>`

**Hint**: You can use these for your loop rather than `range(0,7)`

```
for student in names:
```

or, even better,  see [zip lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

```
for (student, score) in zip(names, scores):
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `zip` function, you can combine the two `lists` together in an easy to use 1-to-1 group of `tuples`.

```
names=['Jim','Sarah','Jason','Lynne','Ginny','Joe','Susan']
scores=['88','92','95','84','85','92','89']
data = zip(names, scores) # <- ('Jim', '88'), ('Sarah', '92'), ...

stud = input('Enter the student's name: ')
for (student, score) in data:
    if (stud == student):
        print('{} -> {}'.format(student, score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Python dictionaries for that:

```
student_scores = {'Jim': 88, 'Sarah': 92, 'Jason': 95}
```

and so on...
Then you can call for each of them like so;

```
name = input("Please enter student's name: ")
print(name + 'has a score of ' + student_scores[name])
```