# Compare lists pairwise and return only the values that are greater in list1

Tags: python, list, comparison, pairwise

Is there a way in python, to compare a value in one list with the value of the same index in a second list?

For example: I want to see if the value in `list1[0] > list2[0] and list1[1] > list2[1]` and do that for the entire list, but **return only the values that are greater in `list1`**.

(Note I only want to compare a number in `list1` that directly aligns with the same index in `list2`. so `list1[0]` is only tested against `list2[0]` and not `list2[1]` or `list2[2]` etc.)

```
list1 = [100, 223, 335, 143, 218]
list2 = [75, 245, 400, 86, 500]
```

Comment: At the very least you could do this with a basic loop. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, you mean ***"compare lists pairwise"***. Are they guaranteed to have the same length? Do you want it in native Python, or pandas, or both?

Comment: If you're looking for a pythonic solution, read about the [`zip()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python) function.

Answer (score 3):

If you wouldn't mind using [`numpy()`](http://www.numpy.org/), you can just use advanced indexing to get the elements in `list1` greater than their respective value in `list2`:

```
In [7]: list1 = np.array([100, 223, 335, 143, 218])
   ...: list2 = np.array([75, 245, 400, 86, 500])
   ...:

In [8]: list1[list1 > list2]
Out[8]: array([100, 143])
```

If you end up wanting to do this calculation on very large lists, using a library such as `numpy()` will increase your performance quite a bit:

```
In [5]: a = np.random.rand(10000)

In [6]: b = np.random.rand(10000)

In [7]: %timeit a[a > b]
56.5 µs ± 1.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit [i for i, j in zip(a, b) if i >j]
1.83 ms ± 28.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Likewise in pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can [`zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python) the two lists togather, and compare the values:

```
>>> list1 = [100, 223, 335, 143, 218]
>>> list2 = [75, 245, 400, 86, 500]
>>> 
>>> for i, j in zip(list1, list2): print i, j, i < j
... 
100 75 False
223 245 True
335 400 True
143 86 False
218 500 True
```

To filter the larger values from list1, use list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i, j in zip(list1, list2) if i >j]
[100, 143]
```

Comment: The output the OP wants is "only the values that are greater in `list1`"

Comment: @smci Thanks for pointing that out, have added in the answer.

Comment: How do you get a list comprehension version but that only yields the items from list1? i.e. compress the `None` out of `[i1 if (i1>i2) else None for i1,i2 in zip(list1, list2)] = [100, None, None, 143, None]`

Comment: @smci I didn't understand you.. Are you suggesting that None is needed in the final result for cases where `i <= j`?

Comment: No @mu-無, I'm asking the total opposite: how to *remove* it from the list-comprehension version, so you get your desired result.