# how to concatenate strings in order?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have an Excel document with following inputs:

Row 1: Name of the product- 7up soft drink
Row 2: Diffrent varients- 600ml;1.25lt;2.25lt;600ml-lemon;2.25lt-lemon
Row 3: price of its Vareints- 35;60;90;35;90

I want the output to look like this

```
7up soft dring 600 ml        35
7up soft drink 1.25ltr       60
7up soft drink 2.25ltr       90
7up soft drink 600ml lemon   35
7up soft drink 2.25ltr lemon 90
```

I have come this far using python

```
import os
import pandas as pd


os.chdir('/Users/apple/Desktop')

tab1 = pd.read_excel('master.xlsx')
tab1['measure'] = tab1['measure'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
tab1['measure'] = tab1['measure'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';'))
tab1['price'] = tab1['price'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
tab1['price'] = tab1['price'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';'))


test = tab1.iloc[13]

tdc = dict.fromkeys(test.index)
for i in tdc.keys():
    tdc[i] = []

tls = []
for i, j in zip(test['measure'],test['price']):
    tls.append([test['products'] + ' ' + i, i, int(j)])

for x in tls:
    for i, j in zip(['products', 'measure', 'price'], x):
        tdc[i].append(j)
```

I got this output

Measure
list
['600ml', '1.25lt', '2.25lt', '600ml-lemon', '2.25lt-lemon']
Price
list
[35, 60, 90, 35, 90]
Products
list
['7up soft dring 600 ml',
 '7up soft drink 1.25ltr',
 '7up soft drink 2.25ltr',
'7up soft drink 600ml lemon',
'7up soft drink 2.25ltr lemon']

*How to assign price list to product list?*

Comment: Please provide an example of how you want the output to look like.

Comment: you can see example output in the beginning of the question

Comment: Sorry, didn't have my reading glasses on...

Answer (score 2):

Since the price list and product list are synchronized (the first product has the first price, the second product as the second price, etc.), you can use a simple for loop:

```
for i in range(len(product_list)):
    print('{}\t{}'.format(product_list[i], price_list[i]))
```

If you want to create a new list:

```
output = []
for i in range(len(product_list)):
    output.append('{} {}'.format(product_list[i], price_list[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine data from two lists. A way to do this is to use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) or [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).

See e.g. [Zip lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

A one-liner that produces your desired output:

```
print('\n'.join(['{:29}{}'.format(product, price) for product, price in zip(test['products'], test['price'])]))
```

Example:

```
>>> test = {
...     'products': [
...         '7up soft dring 600 ml',
...         '7up soft drink 1.25ltr',
...         '7up soft drink 2.25ltr',
...         '7up soft drink 600ml lemon',
...         '7up soft drink 2.25ltr lemon',
...     ],
...     'price': [
...         35,
...         60,
...         90,
...         35,
...         90,
...     ]
... }

# Get the required textual output:
>>> print('\n'.join(['{:29}{}'.format(product, price) for product, price in zip(test['products'], test['price'])]))
7up soft dring 600 ml        35
7up soft drink 1.25ltr       60
7up soft drink 2.25ltr       90
7up soft drink 600ml lemon   35
7up soft drink 2.25ltr lemon 90

# Get a list with (product, price) tuples
>>> zip(test['products'], test['price'])
[('7up soft dring 600 ml', 35), ('7up soft drink 1.25ltr', 60), ('7up soft drink 2.25ltr', 90), ('7up soft drink 600ml lemon', 35), ('7up soft drink 2.25ltr lemon', 90)]
```

Comment: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: I believe `EOF while parsing` has to do with reading the data and not the processing of the dicts.