# combinding each items for both list separet.py

Tags: python, pyrevit

I have tried to search for the answer but I can't find it.

I have two lists. Both lists have **71 items**.

I want every index in both lists to be combined.

- [These two list that I want to combine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGxwX.png)
- [This is what I get but it is not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3muop.png)
- [This is the result that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HyOB.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question as text rather than as images so that others can view it more easily and copy and paste if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
extensions =['.sp1', '.sp1', '.sp2']
my_numbers =[4, 16, 128]
new_list = []

for x in range(len(my_numbers)):
    new_list.append("".join([str(my_numbers[x]), extensions[x]]))

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['4.sp1', '16.sp1', '128.sp2']
```