# Pair items from 2 lists

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm new to Python and I'm still learning it. I need some help on how to pair items from two lists and also how to implement custom pairing if one list has more items than the other list.

Example if both lists are the same length:

```
List1 = [Drew, Ken]
List2 = [Ralph, Kevin]
```

Output should be like this:

```
Drew and Ralph
Ken and Kevin
```

Another example if one list has one extra item:

```
List1 = [Drew, Ken, Mat]
List2 = [Ralph, Kevin]
```

Output should be like this:

```
Drew and Ralph
Ken and Kevin
Mat is alone
```

Last example if the one list has two extra items:

```
List1 = [Drew, Ken, Mat, Jay]
List2 = [Ralph, Kevin]
```

Output should be like this:

```
Drew and Ralph
Ken and Kevin
Mat and Jay
```

Comment: `Last example if the other list having two extra index`, could you perhaps explain how this should generalize?

Comment: if list1 is having 4 index and list2 only have 2 index. then the last 2 index of list1 should be paired

Comment: If you can clarify more it will be nice to understand your purpose

Comment: So there are only these 3 possibilities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zip lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

Comment: yes thats for now that i want to solve

Comment: Reduce your non trivial cases to a trivial case. Ie append to the second list before zipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this solution which covers all the scenarios, which is scalable and preserves the order of all items in each list:

```
from itertools import chain, islice, zip_longest

def partners(l1, l2):
  length = min(len(l1), len(l2))                   # Number of common items
  big_list = chain(*zip(l1, l2), islice(l1, length, None), islice(l2, length, None))
  for who, partner in zip_longest(big_list, big_list):
    print(f'{who} and {partner}' if partner else f'{who} is alone')

List1 = ['Drew', 'Ken']
List2 = ['Ralph', 'Kevin']
print("Matched Pairs")
partners(List1, List2)

List1 = ['Drew', 'Ken', 'Mat']
List2 = ['Ralph', 'Kevin']
print("\nUnmatched Pairs")
partners(List1, List2)

List1 = ['Drew', 'Ken', 'Mat', 'Jay']
List2 = ['Ralph', 'Kevin']
print("\nSuperfluous Pairs")
partners(List1, List2)

List1 = ['Drew']
List2 = []
print("\nSingle Player")
partners(List1, List2)

List1 = []
List2 = []
print("\nNobody")
partners(List1, List2)
```

> Matched Pairs
>
> Drew and Ralph
>
> Ken and Kevin
>
> ---
>
> Unmatched Pairs
>
> Drew and Ralph
>
> Ken and Kevin
>
> Mat is alone
>
> ---
>
> Superfluous Pairs
>
> Drew and Ralph
>
> Ken and Kevin
>
> Mat and Jay
>
> ---
>
> Single Player
>
> Drew is alone
>
> ---
>
> Nobody

The way this works is `big_list` consists of the following:

1. Zip (Pair) up one from each list and flatten that list (`*zip(l1, l2)`)
2. The list of items in `l1` not in `l2`
3. The list of items in `l2` not in `l1`

This results in big_list having the universal order of all partners as [a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, ...] where same letter = partner.

Then we used the [`grouper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) recipe and partner everyone up and loop through it with any unpaired partnered with `"No one"`.

Comment: its working. but when i try making list1 with 5 index and list2 with 3 index there is an error. There is "is with" and "no one" together in the last line when printing it

Comment: @Faded, are you sure? I tested with `List1, List2 = ['Drew', 'Ken', 'Mat', 'Jay', 'Faded'], ['Ralph', 'Kevin', 'LaughDonor']`, which is where `len(List1) == 5` and `len(List2) == 3` as you explain in your comment. And this works without error.

Comment: This solution utilizes some advanced functions in Python which may not be suitable for homework (as you have explained in recent previous questions asked). I don't suggest turning this in unless you completely understand what is happening here.

Comment: @Faded, Still works. You may have a typo in your implementation.

Comment: sorry for typo again. its with 5 index and 4 index. thats the final

Comment: oh its working in your code. but when i try it in my code, its not working. my bad sir, im sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204964/discussion-between-sunny-patel-and-faded).

Answer (score 1):

Match the list sizes and zip them.

```py
>>> l1 = ['Pedro', 'Rodrigues', 'Faded']
>>> l2 = ['Someone']
>>> for _ in range(abs(len(l1) - len(l2))):
...     l2.append('No one')
... 
>>> for who, with_who in zip(l1, l2):
...     print(f'{who} is with {with_who}')
... 
Pedro is with Someone
Rodrigues is with No one
Faded is with No one
>>>
```

Comment: it works if other list having only 1 extra index, but how can you pair the last two index of list1 if list1 having 2 more index to list2?

Comment: @Faded I've updated the example to have a diff of 2 between the list lens, I believe that is the concern you brought forward. The only situation where this fails is if `l1`'s len is actually smaller than `l2`'s len, otherwise `l2` will be appended to match `l1`'s len. Does that address your question?

Comment: Instead of `max(len(l1), len(l2)) - min(len(l1), len(l2))`, could also do `abs(len(l2) - len(l1))`. Also, maybe you could incorporate [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)?

Comment: OP's last example shows that the Rodrigues and Faded should be paired.

Comment: @SunnyPatel it is ambiguous, then, from where should you start merging. Either from the end or the point of difference. I did miss it. But it boils down to the same reduction to a normal zip.

Comment: This also mutates the original lists, which is undesirable.

Comment: @jarmod well, don't mutate them then, should not be that difficult if you got that far.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I'm not the OP. I'm making a general comment that if you write a function to calculate a result given some input data, you should not modify that input data.

Comment: @jarmod I agree. That is what is known as side effects. They are better avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Using Zip makes up only for the first case you described. But if you just want the job done, then you can use this.

```
list1 = ["Manish","Kalol","Haha","Ram","lala"]
list2 = ["lol","Hmmmm"]

if len(list1)>=len(list2):
    biggerlist = list1
    smallerlist = list2
else:
    smallerlist = list1
    biggerlist  =list2

for i in range(len(smallerlist)):    
    print(biggerlist[i] + " with "+ smallerlist[i])

for i in range(len(smallerlist),len(biggerlist)-1 ,2):
    print(biggerlist[i] + " with " + biggerlist[i+1])

if(not (len(biggerlist)-len(smallerlist))%2==0):
    print(biggerlist[len(biggerlist)-1] + " is alone")
```

Comment: it works, but there is a problem when there are 5 index for list1 and 3 index for list2. "is alone" should not be appearing.

Comment: It should be fine now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a beginning and i can improve it with some time in a simple way.

```
List1 = ['Drew', 'Ken']
List2 = ['Ralph', 'Kevin']

Listx = list(zip(List1, List2))
for item in Listx:
    print(f'{item[0]} and {item[1]}')
```

Comment: yes, i already tried using zip. but i want a for loop with no zip to solve this problem.

Comment: I can make it but not in simple code sadly, I will try my best simple way.