# How can I match and output the elements from the result of the .predict(x) method with the elements from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I have the following code:

```
# Load model
with open('text_classifier.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    countVec, model = pickle.load(f)

#Convert to bag of words
results = countVec.transform(commentsInput)

# predict converted text with the trained model
predictionsNew = model.predict(results)

print(predictionsNew)
```

The output from the `print(predictionsNew)` is as follows: `[[1 0 1 0 1 0]]`

When I do `type(predictionsNew)` it returns the type of output as `numpy.ndarray`

Each value in that array corresponds to a label from my dataset, and tells me if the input matches that label. For example, lets say each value corresponds to this array `labels = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`.

I would like to loop through the first array and second array and produce an output as follows:

```
a = 1
b = 0
c = 1
d = 0
e = 1
f = 0
```

What is the easiest way I can achieve this?

UPDATE:
I believe the array of numbers contains just one element. So basically I would like to split this single element into 6 different elements which correspond to my labels array.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Can you be more specific about what you're struggling with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zip lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```py
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
b = np.ndarray((5,), buffer=np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0]), dtype=int) 

for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print(f"{x} = {y}")
```

Outputs:

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 0
d = 1
e = 0
```

Comment: Yup, glad it did. :)