# Appending two lists to one list in a specific way

Tags: python, list

Let's say, I have two lists:

```
[a, b] and [c,d]
```

How can I get the following array as a result in Python?

```
[a, c]
[b, d]
```

Comment: You want a list of lists?

Comment: no an array by concatenating two lists so I can get the result that is requested

Comment: They are called lists, often confused with arrays. Expected output is `[ [a,c], [b, d] ]` right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zip lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numpy solution:

```py
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
joint_array = np.asarray((a, b)).T
```

Answer (score 7):

Zip those lists.

```
list(map(list, zip(list1,list2)))
```

IDLE Output:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2]
>>> list2 = [10,11]
>>> list(map(list, zip(list1,list2)))
[[1, 10], [2, 11]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you specifically mentioned in the comments that you don't want a list of lists but rather a concatenation of the two lists:

```
[a,b]+[c,d]
```

the result will be [a,b,c,d]

otherwise if this is not what you wanted Gauri's or user2653663's answer might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to create two new list variables with the columnwise concatenations you can do this:

```
list1 = ["a", "b"]
list2 = ["c", "d"]

list3,list4 = [list(z) for z in zip(list1,list2)]
print(list3) 
print(list4) 

# ['a', 'c']
# ['b', 'd']
```