# How to add oval brackets when adding to a list in python

Tags: python, list, range

The function merges two lists of the same length, the first of strings, the second of integers.

The function is:

```
def switchlist(n,m):
f=[]
z = range(0,len(m))
for k in z:
    f.append(n[k])
    f.append(m[k])
return f
```

The list is correct, except that it returns: `['yes', 2, 'always', 4]`, instead of:
`[('yes', 2), ('always', 4)]` (if those are the two strings and the two integers)

Does anybody know how to fix the brackets?

Comment: `f.append((n[k], m[k]))`

Comment: it may look the same but there is a difference: the first list has 4 elements -> 2 strings and 2 ints; the second list has 2 elements -> both tuples and each tuple has first string and last int.

Comment: You might want to simplify to `f = list(zip(n, m))`

Comment: @PacketLoss That worked. Never thought it would be so simple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zip lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

Comment: Yes it does, it was a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `zip` would work. First, it needs to be a list. So `f = list(zip(n, m))`
Or at the first, you could make `f = [(), ()]` and append it. Zipping is easier.