# is there andy synchronization problem in multiprocessing of python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The program is below, I use the function imap_unorder in the package multiprocessing for python

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x,x*x

x_list = []
y_list = []
with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for x,y in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(4)):
        x_list.append(x)
        y_list.append(y)
```

Is the x_list and y_list keeping consistent ？

i know that the funciton imap_unordered doesn't process the input iterator orderly. but when outputing x and y, can them appended to the list at the same time?

`x_list = [0,3,1,2]`and `y_list = [0,9,1,4]` is a right example

but i don't want to output such as `x_list = [0,3,1,2]`and `y_list = [0,1,9,4]`

thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping consistent"? What do you expect/hope the result might be?

Comment: i know that the funciton imap_unordered doesn't process the input iterator orderly. but when outputing x and y, can them appended to the list at the same time?

Comment: You answered your own question :-)

Comment: I don't understand what is the question here... Did you run this and got the false result, or are you asking if it's possible to get it?

Comment: OP added some specifics of what they're seeing after I commented.

Comment: @Tomerikoo you are right. I am thinking whether it's possible to get that

Comment: Ah the details the OP added of the “I don’t want to output such as...” are hypothetical. No that can’t happen. As I said in my answer, by the time the x,y values are returned from imap_unordered() are being added to x_list and y_list you are back in the main process which is **not** being executed concurrently. Yes there are many other potential concurrency traps you can fall into with multiprocessing, but that’s not one of.them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x,y values will always be consistent because you're back in the main process when you combine the results of `f()` into `x_list` and `y_list`.

To make this clearer, make the `f()` calls take varying times, like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random
import time

def f(x):
    print( f"{x=}" )
    delay = 2.0*random.random()
    print( f"{delay=}" )
    time.sleep(delay)
    return x,x*x

x_list = []
y_list = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as pool:
        for x,y in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
            x_list.append(x)
            y_list.append(y)
    print( f"{x_list=}" )
    print( f"{y_list=}" )
```

And you might get output like this, noting how concurrent execution of `f()` is causing interleaving of its print statements with other processes also executing their `f()`:

```
x=0
delay=1.2836811458870878
x=1
delay=0.944416583067992
x=2
x=3
x=4
delay=1.6181526174149976
delay=0.5554265852002582
delay=1.5824716636923408
x=5
delay=0.01722248285756467
x=6
delay=1.8688128104508799
x=7
delay=0.9426899102018951
x=8
delay=0.5319453505012279
x=9
delay=0.24791521653497783
x_list=[5, 3, 8, 9, 1, 7, 0, 4, 2, 6]
y_list=[25, 9, 64, 81, 1, 49, 0, 16, 4, 36]
```

Examining the print output the x=5 has shortest time to sleep so is first in the results list. Similar x=6 has the longest sleep and so is last in the output.

Comment: thanks, it's a great example

Comment: I am confused that the error only happened if two processes output at the same time almostly, is different delay helpful?

Comment: Which error happened?

Comment: for example, `x_list = [0,3,1,2]` and `y_list = [0,1,9,4]`

Comment: I can't see any intermingling like that. Are you on Linux?

Comment: I didn't see that too. But I am afraid of this happening

Comment: What? So you’ve not seen this happen. Right. If you worry about that, well, I wouldn’t bother with software because there are bigger concerns like the sun may not rise in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

The pairs will be internally consistent, but with `imap_unordered()` you're not guaranteed they're in the same order as the input iterable.

You could also use `zip()` to transpose a list-of-pairs into a pair-of-lists:

```
with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    pairs = pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10))
    x_list, y_list = zip(*pairs)
```

Comment: Where can I get more information? i don't know how this happened. thanks

Comment: If you're wondering about `zip`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python