# How do I print two for lists into a single line

Tags: python

Just started out in python and I would like to mass print a list for a game without having to do tedious work. I have 2 lists where I need each row in the list to be printed only once, both lists corresponding to each other. For example row 1 in engramlist would be printed along with row 1 in levellist as with row 2 in both list and so on. However I am not sure how to do that as my code will print out one row in engramlist with every single row in levellist. If someone can help me out, it would be appreciated.

This is my code.

```
engrams = []
engram_file = open("engramlist.txt")
for line in engram_file:
    engrams.append(line[:-1])
engram_file.close()

levels = []
level_file = open("levellist.txt")
for line in level_file:
    levels.append(line[:-1])
level_file.close()

for classname in engrams:
    for level_requirement in levels:
        print('"OverrideNamedEngramEntries=(EngramClassName="' + classname + '",EngramHidden=false,EngramLevelRequirement=' + level_requirement + ',RemoveEngramPreReq=false)')
```

Comment: I'd say it's related/duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("engramlist.txt", 'r') as file:
    engrams = [line[:-1] for line in file.readlines()]
with open("levellist.txt", 'r') as file:
    levels = [line[:-1] for line in file.readlines()]

for engram, level in zip(engrams, levels):
    print(engram, level)
```