# How I can combine (zip together) two or more lists?

Tags: python

I want to combine two (or more) lists in a single list where each entry in the new list groups items from the original lists. I want to go from this

[image]

to this

[image]

The First list is string with line breaks as delimiters.
And other list is int with line breaks as delimiters.
Here is the code

```
with SampClient(address='rp.valrisegaming.com', port=7777) as client:
        print("Connected Clients")
        print("Name                       | Score".format(client=client))
        print("==================================")
        players = [client.name for client in client.get_server_clients_detailed()]
        sp = '\n'
        sp = sp.join(players)
        score = [client.score for client in client.get_server_clients_detailed()]
        ss =('\n'.join(map(str, score)))
        print(f"{sp}:{ss}")
```

Comment: Is it important that you need a list? Wouldn't a dictionary be better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zip lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can run through one of the list and append its items to the other list. for example :-

```
list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [4,5,6]

for item in list_1:
    list_2.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
players =["a", "b", "c"]
score = ["1", "2", "3"]

res = ["["+ players[i] + "] : " + score[i] for i in range(len(players))]

for e in res:
    print(e)
```

Gives output

```
[a] : 1
[b] : 2
[c] : 3
```

Comment: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/796077200981884998/819526594896986122/Capture.PNG)This is one more SS

Comment: There is a mistake score is int str(score[i]) like this
Thanks Working

Comment: How can i add one more list?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp), which saves data as key-value pairs. This is perfect for your situation, where you need a name (key) and their score (value). An example at merging your name and value to a dictionary can be like so:

```py
# Initialize dictionary
merged_data = {}

# For each index, for each player
for i in range(len(players)):
    # Add the player with that index, and their score to the dictionary
    merged_data[players[i]] = score[i]

print(merged_data)
```

Comment: Thanks,
And what about if there is 3rd or 4th list?