# Appending lists together in a neat way

Tags: python

My task right now is to append two list together. Of course I know that I can do:

```
Names = ["Samson", "Daniel", "Jason", "Delion"]
Ages = [16, 18, 34, 27]
Names.extend(age)
```

However, what i am attempting to do is print these lists in the format of:

```
Samson   16
Daniel   18
Jason    34
Delion   27
```

With my current attempt, all ive been able to do is print in the format:

```
Samson, Daniel, Jason, Delion, 16, 18, 34, 27
```

Greatly appreciated if I could get some sort of help on how to do this.

Comment: `zip(Names, Ages)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zip lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python)

Comment: Also, I'd go against `\t` as the separator. Best to use `ljust` or just formatting the string with such as `f"{name:<10}{age}"`. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676646/how-can-i-fill-out-a-python-string-with-spaces)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary here.

```py
Names = ["Samson", "Daniel", "Jason", "Delion"]
Ages = [16, 18, 34, 27]
a_dict = dict(zip(Names, Ages))
for key in a_dict.keys():
    print(key, a_dict[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` function.

```py
names = ["Samson", "Daniel", "Jason", "Delion"]
ages = [16, 18, 34, 27]
new_list = list(zip(names, ages))
for name, age in new_list:
    print(f"{name}\t{age}")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Names = ["Samson", "Daniel", "Jason", "Delion"]
Ages = [16, 18, 34, 27]

data = zip(Names, Ages)

for person in data:
    print(person[0], person[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `zip` function

```
Names = ["Samson", "Daniel", "Jason", "Delion"]
Ages = [16, 18, 34, 27]
for name, age in zip(Names, Ages):
    print(f"{name}\t{age}")
```