# Iterating 2 permutation sets

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, permutation

Let's say I start with these two hypothetical lists: color and shape.

I have 15 colors and let's say a recursively infinite number of shapes (like number of sides of a regular ngon). At its most basic it starts like

```
color_list, shape_list = [1], [1]
```

up to the complexity I mentioned, one example of length 3 might be

```
color_list, shape_list = [15,9,7], [1,3,7]
```

These numbers are arbitrary to compare one particular permutation that combines color 15 with shape 1, color 9 with shape 3, color 7 with shape 7.

How would I create an iteration over every possible permutation that returns something from the `[1], [1]` up to say `[15,15,15,15,15], [n,n,n,n,n]`?

Comment: What is expected output & please include what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is not what the word "permutation" typically means. Based on what you've given us, I think you're either looking for [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) or [the `zip` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704860/zip-lists-in-python), and I can't tell which right now.

Comment: You're looking to generate 1- through k-tuples of value pairs, with the first value in the pair ranging from 1 through m and the second value ranging from 1 through n, containing every possible combination of values? (the format you're asking for would then be those tuples of pairs unzipped into two lists - but that's trivial, and it's quite likely you'll want to process them in pairs anyway)

Comment: "that returns something from the [1], [1] up to say [15,15,15,15,15], [n,n,n,n,n]?" I can't understand what this means. The question is almost certainly a duplicate, but I can't tell **which** question it duplicates without a proper specfication. For the given input `color_list, shape_list = [15,9,7], [1,3,7]`, please show the **exact, complete** desired output. I can't tell you how to make "all the permutations" (assuming that is the correct word, which it might not be) because right now I can't tell what you expect *one* of them to look like, nor can I tell *how many* you expect here.

Comment: "I have 15 colors and let's say a recursively infinite number of shapes" I can't understand this. "Recursively infinite" does not make any sense at all. I also need an explanation of how an integer is intended to represent either a colour or a shape.

Comment: Also, the number of sides of a regular N-gon is N, not infinity. If N happens to equal infinity, we usually call that shape a "circle".

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are trying to do the following -

1. Create color, shape combinations with some lower and upper limit for each (color = 3, shape = 5), (color = 1, shape = 99) etc.
2. Then you are trying to permute over these color combinations for each permutation order from 1 to m (in your example m = 5)

Here is a piece of code that should get you something similar. Please do note, this will explode exponentially, so avoid larger limits.

```
import itertools

color_i = 1
color_n = 5

shape_i = 1
shape_n = 6

permutes = 3

# color, shape combos
combos = list(itertools.product(range(color_i, color_n+1), range(shape_i, shape_n+1)))

# create permutations from the color, shape combos
permutations = []
for p in range(permutes):
    for i in itertools.permutations(combos,r=p+1):
        permutations.append(list(zip(*i)))

permutations
```

```
[[(1,), (1,)],
 [(1,), (2,)],
 [(1,), (3,)],
 [(1,), (4,)],
 [(1,), (5,)],
 [(1,), (6,)],
 [(2,), (1,)],
 [(2,), (2,)],
 [(2,), (3,)],
 [(2,), (4,)],
 [(2,), (5,)],
 [(2,), (6,)],
 [(3,), (1,)],
 [(3,), (2,)],
 [(3,), (3,)],
 [(3,), (4,)],
 [(3,), (5,)],
 [(3,), (6,)],
 [(4,), (1,)],
 [(4,), (2,)],
 [(4,), (3,)],
 [(4,), (4,)],
 [(4,), (5,)],
 [(4,), (6,)],
 [(5,), (1,)],
 [(5,), (2,)],
 [(5,), (3,)],
 [(5,), (4,)],
 [(5,), (5,)],
 [(5,), (6,)],
 [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
 [(1, 1), (1, 3)],
 ...,
 [(1, 4), (1, 2)],
 [(1, 4), (1, 3)],
 [(1, 4), (1, 4)],
 [(1, 4), (1, 5)],
 [(1, 4), (1, 6)],
 [(1, 5), (1, 1)],
 [(1, 5), (1, 2)],
 [(1, 5), (1, 3)],
 [(1, 5), (1, 4)],
 [(1, 5), (1, 5)],
 [(1, 5), (1, 6)],
 [(1, 1), (2, 1)],
 [(1, 1), (2, 3)],
 [(1, 1), (2, 4)],
 [(1, 1), (2, 5)],
 [(1, 1), (2, 6)],
 [(1, 2), (2, 1)],
 [(1, 2), (2, 2)],
 ...,
 [(4, 4), (3, 6)],
 [(4, 5), (3, 1)],
 [(4, 5), (3, 2)],
 [(4, 5), (3, 3)],
 [(4, 5), (3, 4)],
 [(4, 5), (3, 5)],
 [(4, 5), (3, 6)],
 [(4, 1), (4, 1)],
 [(4, 1), (4, 2)],
 [(4, 1), (4, 3)],
 [(4, 1), (4, 4)],
 [(4, 1), (4, 5)],
 ...,
 [(5, 5), (6, 2)],
 [(5, 5), (6, 3)],
 [(5, 5), (6, 4)],
 [(5, 5), (6, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3)],
 ...,
 [(1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 1)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 3, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 3, 1)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 3, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 3, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 3, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 3, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 3, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 1)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 4), (1, 3, 1)],
 [(1, 1, 4), (1, 3, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 4), (1, 3, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 4), (1, 3, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 4), (1, 3, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 4), (1, 3, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 3, 1)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 3, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 3, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 3, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 3, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 5), (1, 3, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 4, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 4, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 4, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 1), (1, 4, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 4, 1)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 4, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 4, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 4, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 4, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 2), (1, 4, 6)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 4, 1)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 4, 2)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 4, 3)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 4, 4)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 4, 5)],
 [(1, 1, 3), (1, 4, 6)],
 ...]
```

#### How it works -

1. Create `itertools.product` using ranges for color and shape. This gives you all possible (color, shape) tuples.
2. For permutation order 1 to m (1, 2, 3, ..., m) permute over this list of all possible tuples k times where 1>=k>=m
3. Use `list(zip(*i))` on each generated permutation to transpose it from `[(color1, shape1), (color2, shape2), (color3, shape3)]` to `[(color1, color2, color3), (shape1, shape2, shape3)]`

Comment: Glad to help. Asking a good question on SO takes a bit of time to learn as well, so don't feel discouraged. A few downvotes don't matter as you can very quickly reverse them by either improving your question or just constant participation on the platform. A good way to start would be to read [ask] and [mre]. Please take all the feedback constructively and very soon you will find yourself very comfortable on SO! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of parameters:

- the number of possible colours (for example, 2)
- the number of possible shapes (for example, 3)
- the number of colour / shape combinations (for example, 4)

In Python:

```
n_colours = 2
colours = range(1, n_colours+1)

n_shapes = 3
shapes = range(1, n_shapes+1)

# creating a list of all possible combinations of colours and shapes:
all_pairs = list(product(colours, shapes))
```

You asked to get the combinations in two separate lists of the colours and the corresponding shapes. It seems more sensible to generate them as tuples of pairs instead:

```
from itertools import product

max_len = 4
tuples = [t for p in [product(all_pairs, repeat=n) for n in range(1, max_len+1)] for t in p]
```

But if you wanted to generate them as pairs of separate colours and shapes instead, here's an implementation that generates them one after the other:

```
from itertools import product


def all_colour_shape_pairs(n_colours, n_shapes, max_len):
    ps = list(product(range(1, n_colours+1), range(1, n_shapes+1)))
    for t in [t for p in [product(ps, repeat=n) for n in range(1, max_len+1)] for t in p]:
        yield zip(*t)


result = all_colour_shape_pairs(2, 3, 4)
while input('Press enter for another, or enter "x" to stop:') != 'x':
    print(tuple(next(result)))
```

Output

```
((1,), (1,))
((1,), (2,))
((1,), (3,))
((2,), (1,))
...
((2,), (3,))
((1, 1), (1, 1))
((1, 1), (1, 2))
...
((2, 2), (3, 3))
((1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1))
((1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2))
...
```

And if you want the generator to keep generating results "inifinitely" (or rather, to stop when the computer runs out of resources and is unable to continue):

```
from itertools import product


def all_colour_shape_pairs(n_colours, n_shapes, max_len):
    ps = list(product(range(1, n_colours+1), range(1, n_shapes+1)))
    n = 1
    while True:
        for t in product(ps, repeat=n):
            yield zip(*t)
        n += 1


result = all_colour_shape_pairs(2, 3, 4)
while input('Press enter for another, or enter "x" to stop:') != 'x':
    print(tuple(next(result)))
```