# Using foreach with more than one container in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

I have two `QStringList` instances over which I want to iterate at the same time. Using a `for` loop and two iterators it would work.

But as I do it pretty often and whould like to reduce typing, is there a possibility to do it with Qt's `foreach` macro (I'm using Qt 4.8) or probably even a special macro for this?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552277/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-two-or-more-containers-simultaneously and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286755/how-can-i-iterate-over-two-vectors-simultaneously-using-boost-foreach

Comment: @m.s. These are not about Qt's foreach. I don't use boost and unfortunatelly don't have C++11 in this project.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz i don't think it's possible, since qt's foreach is simple a macro defined within qt and it could only support item and container separated by ",", all other would produce error