# Indices vs iterators

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have two vectors of the same length:

```
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
```

if I have to iterate over both of it, which approach should I use:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) { //...}
```

or

```
for(auto i = v1.begin(), j=v2.begin(); i != v1.end(); ++i, ++j) {//...}
```

Do both of these approaches always equal when optimized by compiler?

Comment: You're comparing two different things, in the first loop you're referring only one vector.

Comment: @MarounMaroun probably it is assumed that `v1.size() == v2.size()`.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286755/how-can-i-iterate-over-two-vectors-simultaneously-using-boost-foreach

Comment: @nmerci If you are sure about both are having same length first one seems good fit

Comment: Instead of parallel vectors, use a `vector<data>` where `data` defines the two integers

Comment: *"Do both of these approaches always equal when optimized by compiler?"* Measure.

Comment: If you use the index loop, access the vector with `at`. If you use the iterator loop, set the condition to `i != v1.end() && j != v2.end()`. Anything other is needlessly unsafe, as you might access `v2` out-of-bounds.